# Porque a prática do "parâmetro constante" só existe no C

Tags: c, constantes

Em C, existe a prática de aplicar o modificador "const" em parâmetros de função quando a função não tem o objetivo de alterar o parâmetro. Como neste código:

```
char process_string(const char *str);
```

Porque em outras linguagens não existe essa prática? Porque não é comum ser ver coisa do tipo:

```
public String processString(final String str);
```

Comment: Na verdade, *final* em parâmetros Java é em geral uma boa prática para evitar reuso indevido dos parâmetros como variáveis. Quase ninguém usa porque a maioria dos "javeiros" não estuda além do básico e o restante tem preguiça.

Comment: Que interessante. Poderia me dizer onde eu posso ficar sabendo dessas boas práticas?

Answer (score 11):

Em primeiro lugar, os códigos que você postou não são equivalentes: no primeiro caso, o ponteiro `str` pode ser reatribuído à vontade, mas o **conteúdo** da string apontada não (mais detalhes [nessa pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10091825/520779)). No segundo, a referência `str` não pode ser modificada, mas o conteúdo do objeto a princípio poderia ser - se `String` já não fosse imutável (estou pensando em Java, mas se você se referia a outra linguagem favor especificar).

[Esse exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/aMaWpJ) mostra isso claramente:

```
char *process_string(const char *str) {
    str = outra_string; // Pode mudar o ponteiro à vontade
    //str[0] = '1';     // Não pode mexer no conteúdo
    return str;
}

char *process_string_2(char * const str) {
    //str = outra_string; // Não pode mudar o ponteiro
    str[0] = '2';         // Pode mexer no conteúdo à vontade
    return str;
}
```

Por que isso não é comum em outras linguagens? Infelizmente não sei dizer... Seria extremamente útil um compilador que garantisse o contrato que "esse método não tem efeitos colaterais [nesse parâmetro pelo menos]" mas não faço ideia da dificuldade de se implementar (em particular em linguagens orientadas por objeto, que não suportam aritmética de ponteiro e fazem uso extensivo de referências).

E por falar em referências, a principal razão pela qual não se vê muitos parâmetros `final` é que é comum as referências a objetos serem passadas **por valor**. Ou seja, o objeto não é copiado, mas a referência para ele sim. Dessa forma, que mal tem a função reatribuir seus próprios parâmetros? Só ela os vê mesmo... E por essa mesma razão é difícil ver uma função em C com parêmetros tal qual o `process_string_2` do exemplo acima.

O único caso que eu conheço que um parâmetro `final` pode ser necessário é quando ele for usado num [*closure*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) e a linguagem não der suporte à ["pilha espaguete"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_stack):

```
public void prepararBotao(final String mensagem) {
    final JTextField caixaTexto = this.caixaTexto;
    botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            caixaTexto.setText(mensagem); // Só pode usar "mensagem" aqui porque é final
        }
    });
}
```

(Não conheço a razão exata para isso ser necessário em Java - outras linguagens permitem que os closures acessem atributos não-final sem problemas)

Comment: Apenas lembretes. A ideia de "não pode mudar" também existe nas variáveis *static*... Talvez seja oportuno ampliar o escopo da discussão...  Quanto ao uso em outras linguagens, talvez interessante lembrar de equivalências e diferenças para a diretiva *#define* (que em linguagens como o PHP é um comando).

Comment: Acho que entendi: A prática existe em C porque nesta linguagem a referenciação de variáveis é mais crítica, e para garantir que não haja efeitos colaterais, é necessário o const. Mas há coisas que ainda não ficaram esclarecidas: Como assim passagem por valor usa referências? Passagem por referência não é aquela em que o endereço é se a função alterar o valor da variável, ela alterará o valor da variável que lhe foi passada. Em Java, pelo que eu sei, é tudo por valor.

Comment: @Sid Existe uma diferença entre "ponteiro" e "referência", mas não sei exatamente qual é... De todo modo, o que você disse está correto, tudo é passado por valor. Mas enquanto um **objeto** passado por valor seria copiado (em C++ por exemplo, isso pode acontecer) um **ponteiro a um obejto** passado por valor não faz com que o objeto em si seja copiado.

Comment: @bigown [Feito!](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/215) :)

Comment: Se diz que java passa "o valor da referência". Você não pode tomar o endereço nem explicitamente, de modo que este conceito (endereço) não existe. Em C++ você pode tomar o endereço de uma referência de forma explícita se quiser. Em Java, quando você passa uma variável para uma função, ou atribui o valor de uma variável a outra, é como se estivesse copiando a referência (o ""endereço"") do objeto, não o objeto por ela "apontado". O operador de atribuição "=" apenas atribui nova referência à variável, não copia o objeto referenciado. Para alterar o objeto, só através dos métodos e propriedades.