# Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?

Tags: ponteiro, característica-linguagem, referência

Uma das primeiras coisas que aprendi sobre Java é que essa linguagem "não possui ponteiros, somente referências", seguida de algumas afirmações genéricas de como o primeiro é complexo e o segundo é mais simples. Mas nunca entendi exatamente qual a diferença de um para o outro. Há alguma diferença, ou conceitualmente eles são a mesma coisa?

Esclarecendo, eu sei que nem Java nem a maioria das linguagens que só suporta referências permite que seja feita aritmética com essas referências. Algo como:

```
Object x = ...;
x++;
```

não é permitido. Mas seria isso apenas uma restrição às operações que a linguagem deixa fazer ao mesmo tipo (ponteiro)? Ou são de fato conceitos diferentes?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## TL; DR

Ponteiro é um mecanismo com baixo nível de abstração que contém um endereço de memória para um objeto qualquer. Esse endereço é o foco dele e esse valor pode ser manipulado livremente pela aplicação como um dado qualquer. Muitas linguagens escondem totalmente sua existência.

[image: Mostrando um ponteiro na memória]

Referência é um conceito mais abstrato e nem sempre visível na linguagem. Ela cria um conjunto de dados formado pelo objeto que é o seu foco e a referência que indica onde o objeto está. Essa referência pode ser composta por um ponteiro. A manipulação da referência é limitada, inclusive porque ela dá preferência para a manipulação do objeto.

São duas maneiras de conceituar algo muito parecido e muitas vezes o mesmo. Isto tem implicações nos detalhes de uso, mas servem pro mesmo propósito.

## Introdução

Eu não tenho informações baseadas em estudos confiáveis publicados, então para responder eu me baseio principalmente na Wikipedia e no que sempre aprendi.

Vou tentar dar uma interpretação universal que me parece ser a intenção da pergunta e não para uma tecnologia específica e mostrar quando é algo especifico de uma linguagem sem entrar em detalhes.

## Ponteiro

[Ponteiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29)) é uma construção mais concreta. Ela existe mesmo no nível mais baixo da programação. Um processador manipula ponteiros. Conforme a Wikipedia, um ponteiro - ou apontador para os gajos e gajas do velho continente - é um valor que se refere a outro valor alocado em outra área da memória.

Eu não gosto muito dessa definição por que ela implica que ponteiros só apontam para dados. Ok, qualquer coisa no computador de alguma forma pode ser considerada um dado, até mesmo código. Mas é uma interpretação ambígua. Por isso prefiro ver o ponteiro como um apontamento para alguma área da memória.

Porém, gosto que ele cita a memória. Me parece que o conceito de ponteiro seja mais específico para a memória. Ainda que eu mesmo utilize o termo em outras situações, me parece mais adequado que ele seja usado apenas para o tratamento de memória.

Algumas linguagens permitem manipulação direta de ponteiros em maior ou menor grau. Podemos dizer que essa é uma das formas que ajudam classificar linguagens pelo seu nível de abstração. Ou seja, se a linguagem manipula o ponteiro de forma muito liberal, concreta e direta, a linguagem é mais baixo nível, como é o caso dos Assemblies. Outras linguagens como C, C++, D, Rust, Go, Pascal, só para ficar em alguns exemplos, também fazem uso liberal dos ponteiros mas com algumas limitações e cada uma delas com menos incentivo, fornecendo outras formas mais abstratas de obter o mesmo resultado. Outras linguagens abandonam completamente a manipulação de ponteiros, como o Java, Python e JavaScript. Outras impõem grandes limitações, como o C#. Essas linguagens são mais alto nível.

Provavelmente C é a linguagem *mainstream* que mais incentiva e que mais popularizou o uso de ponteiros. De fato C não possui referências (diretamente). E muitas definições do que é ponteiro irão se confundir com o que se usa em C.

Ponteiros são sempre valores, então parâmetros do tipo ponteiro são passados por valor, ou seja, o endereço guardado no ponteiro é copiado. Há uma independência do que ele está apontando. **Quando você se refere ao ponteiro, está se referindo ao endereço contido nele. Se quer o objeto deste endereço, precisa explicitar isto**.

É comum usar ponteiros para obter performance, afinal ele se aproxima o processamento concreto. Uma das operações comuns em ponteiros é a aritmética, assim manipula o acesso às posições de memória de forma muito fácil e rápida. Claro que sempre há o risco de alguma operação ser irregular e causar resultados indesejados. Ponteiros não costumam ser seguros para manipular indiscriminadamente. Embora sua flexibilidade de fazer, até mesmo, operações potencialmente irregulares é que dá grande poder a ele. Grande poder, grandes responsabilidades. O programador tem que saber tudo o que fazer e como fazer. Ele não automatiza "nada".

Mas não se engane, o ponteiro ainda é uma abstração. O ponteiro é uma forma de se **referenciar** objetos na memória.

## Referência

Uma [referência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))) me parece ser algo mais amplo. Você pode ter referências para algo que vai além da memória. Mesmo na memória você pode ter referências que por si só ainda não podem ser considerados ponteiros. Referência, como o próprio nome diz, se refere a algo, mas esse algo pode ser mais livre. O artigo da Wikipedia diz que ela é um objeto que contém informação que indica dados armazenados em algum outro local ao invés de conter o próprio dado.

Uma referência é composta de duas partes. Um endereço que indica onde o dado está e o próprio dado. Isto é diferente do ponteiro que não tem uma relação direta com o dado. Você não faz muitas operações com referências, não tem aritmética, por exemplo. Você pode trocar o valor da referência mas não pode manipulá-lo livremente. Claro que em memória uma referência direta provavelmente será implementada através de um ponteiro. Mas é possível ter uma referência que não seja um ponteiro.

A referência é um conceito mais abstrato e por isto, dependendo de como ela será usada, esse nível de abstração pode ser um pouco diferente. A forma como se lida com esta referência pode ser diferente. Em alguns casos o programador talvez possa até ignorar que aquilo seja uma referência.

Uma coisa que aprendi lendo os excelentes artigos do Eric Lippert é que uma referência deve ser interpretada como um *alias* para um dado, para um objeto.

Ou seja, é só um nome que damos para o objeto, por isso ela sempre é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). E você pode ter quantos *aliases* quiser para ele. Ter apenas um *alias* tem implicações na forma como o dado será manipulado. Claro que internamente esse *alias* provavelmente será manipulado com ponteiros mas a forma será diferente e principalmente, não será problema do programador.

Quando dizemos que passamos algo por referência, significa que passamos o valor da referência - há uma cópia da referência, mas nossa **intenção** é passar o dado a que ela se refere. É comum, mesmo em linguagens de mais baixo nível que possuem mecanismos próprios de referência, não dar acesso direto ao endereço da referência, porque ele não é importante e sim o seu dado referenciado. Assim, referências são muito mais seguras que ponteiros. **Quando acessamos uma referência, está implícito que queremos acessar seu objeto referenciado**. É até uma questão de semântica clara.

Em linguagens de muito baixo nível, como Assembly e C, não possuem mecanismos que tratam de referências, você as simula com ponteiros. Em outras, como C++ e D, isso pode ser feito explicitamente. Nas linguagens de mais alto nível o uso delas é tão opaco que o programador pode até usá-las sem ter ciência que está usando uma referência. Não importa muito o quanto a linguagem esconda a implementação, se é uma referência, é muito mais fácil manipular que um ponteiro. O fato dela ser menos flexível, dar mais garantias, muitas preocupações são desnecessárias. E até o compilador pode se beneficiar já que ele pode ser mais agressivo por conta das garantias fornecidas pelo mecanismo, o que pode facilitar ter um ganho de performance.

Referências costumam ter informações adicionais além do endereço onde a outra parte está. Pelo menos o seu tamanho e o tipo de informação contida na parte referida são comuns, mesmo que a informação só esteja disponível em tempo de compilação, nas linguagens mais simples.

C++ provavelmente é uma das linguagens onde a diferenciação é mais importante já que ela possui explicitamente tanto ponteiro quanto referência. Em C++ ponteiro e referência são tipos de dados. Claro que algumas linguagens possuem referências embutidas em outros mecanismos. Como é o caso de um *slice* de Go. Mas não é que C, por exemplo, não tenha referências, ela só não tem um mecanismo específico para tratá-las. Elas são conceituadas e manipuladas por completa discrição do programador.

Tanto ponteiro quanto referência são [indireções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

## Intercâmbio de nomenclatura

Tudo que fazemos em estrutura de dados usam referências. E até que precise explicitar que ela é concretizada através de um ponteiro, esta deveria ser a nomenclatura preferencial. Eu e meio mundo intercambiamos os termos quando não é o mais apropriado sem causar grandes prejuízos ou mal-entendidos. Em documentações e outras publicações formais o equívoco não pode ocorrer.

A intenção desta resposta não é esgotar o assunto, mas apenas dirimir as diferenças dos termos já que todos usamos o tempo todo e nem sempre paramos para pensar sobre exatamente o que eles são.

## Conclusão

Como eu comecei, eu não tenho como afirmar, nunca li algo canônico e indiscutível sobre o assunto, até gostaria de ver algo assim, mas o que posso ajudar é mostrar que são conceitos diferentes, um é um mecanismo concreto, poderoso e flexível e o outro é mais abstrato, mais seguro (mais automatizado), mais universal, e mais fácil de entender.

Referência, nas linguagens de mais alto nível, como o Java, é um conceito mais abstrato que indica uma indireção de dado, sequer é um mecanismo acessível ao programador na maioria delas. Ponteiro é um dos mecanismos mais concretos usados para implementar a referência. É importante ter alguma consciência sobre o funcionamento de referências para evitar surpresas mas não é necessário entender profundamente o seu funcionamento. Podemos dizer que nestas linguagens ponteiro, estritamente, nem deveria ser citado. Não que eu esteja pregando alienação do programador.

Não sei se respondi totalmente a dúvida e sei que esta resposta não pode ser considerada definitiva. Não que ela esteja errada também. Mas acredito que os *links* fornecidos ajudam começar a procura por mais informações sobre o assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Difícil escolher, mas aceitei essa resposta pois não só é bastante completa como - apesar de extensa - evidencia de forma bem clara a principal diferença entre os conceitos no meu entender (ver as partes em negrito). As demais respostas também são boas, em particular [a do Miguel Angelo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56491/215) - mais concisa e didática, porém menos precisa e mais focada no C#.

Answer (score 28):

Tanto ponteiro como referência tratam de algo que vou chamar de *"fenômeno de apontamento"*. Assim como no eletromagnetismo temos um único fundamento, e duas formas de observar o efeito desse fundamento.

Vou falar sobre o ponto de vista do C# sobre isso. Ainda assim acredito que esse ponto de vista, transite entre linguagens sem muitos atritos.

### Ponteiro

No ponto de vista do C# pelo menos, ponteiro é um tipo de dado que consta em um endereço de memória e deve apontar para uma dada estrutura, ou pode ser nulo. Se não for nulo, então o ponteiro é considerado inválido caso a estrutura apontada não seja do tipo correto. Ainda assim é possível ter ponteiros do `void`, que apontam para algo indefinido (ou seja, são meros endereços de memória).

- ponteiro void: `void*`
          [image: Ponteiro void]

Ponteiros permitem operar o apontamento com operações matemáticas, e no geral se parecem mais com um número inteiro qualquer do que com um objeto.

[image: Somando números em um ponteiro]

Para ter acesso ao objeto apontado, é necessário usar operadores de `*` ou `->`. O primeiro obtém a estrutura apontada como valor, e o segundo serve para ter acesso direto a um membro da estrutura apontada.

[image: Focando o objeto apontado com <code>*</code>, e indo direto para o membro com <code>-></code>]

Como ponteiros permitem atribuir qualquer valor numérico à variável, eles só podem ser usados em contexto inseguros, marcados com a palavra chave `unsafe`. Isso é causado pois o tipo de dado presente no destino apontado pelo endereço de memória pode não corresponder ao tipo do ponteiro:

[image: Tipo apontado não corresponde ao tipo do ponteiro]

Com ponteiros é possível criar uma cascata de apontamentos, que levam ao objeto final.

- `DateTime****`

  [image: Cascata de apontamentos, com um objeto final]

### Referência

Referência é um tipo de dado que possui por baixo dos panos um ponteiro, mas sem permitir fazer operações matemáticas, e dando acesso direto ao objeto apontado.

[image: O endereço fica oculto do programador]

No C# existem duas formas de referência:

- na passagem de variável para uma função

  ```
  void Metodo(ref int valor)

   == ou ==

  void Metodo(out int valor)
  ```

  Com referências não é possível alterar o valor numérico do endereço, sendo que ao atribuir um valor à referência vai ser alterado o valor apontado e não a referência em si.

  [image: Fazendo <code>x = y</code>]Fazendo `x = y`
- usando tipos-referência (ou classes no C#)

  ```
  class Xpto // Xpto agora é um tipo-referência
  ```

  Com tipos-referência é possível atribuir valor do endereço, usando uma outra referência do mesmo tipo-referência, ou definindo o valor como nulo. Essas são as únicas formas de alterar o valor numérico do ponteiro que está por baixo dos panos em um tipo-referência.

  [image: Atribuindo instâncias de classe] Atribuindo instâncias de classe

O C# permite dupla referência apenas ao passar um tipo-referência por referência para um método.

- `void Metodo(out Xpto classeXpto)`

O acesso à estrutura é feito sem usar operador especial algum. Usa-se a referência como se fosse o próprio tipo referido.

### Comparações

- Tanto referência como ponteiro permitem alterar o objeto apontado, sem alterar o valor numérico do endereço que o representa. Portanto ambos podem ser usados para fazer a *"passagem por referência"*, em que o chamador passar algo para que um método altere.
- Ambos possuem um endereço de memória por baixo dos panos.

### Mesmo fenômeno, dois pontos de vista

Ponteiro/referência podem ser entendidos como duas formas de observar o mesmo fenômeno do "apontamento". Ponteiros observam o fenômeno de apontar a partir da origem do apontamento. Referências observam o fenômeno de apontar a partir do destino do apontamento.

[image: Ponteiro observa da origem, referência observa do destino]Dualidade do mesmo fundamento.

Answer (score 15):

Ponteiros são variáveis que armazenam endereços de memória e permitem referênciá-los.

Referências dizem respeito a objetos ou variáveis específicos, abstraindo-se totalmente o lugar e forma de armazenamento.

Como ponteiros armazenam (e te permitem manipular) endereços, as linguagens que tornam visíveis os ponteiros te dão algumas propriedades como aritmética de ponteiros, aliasing (tratar o mesmo endereço de memória como tipos de dados diferentes) e acesso a endereços inválidos (ainda que esta última seja normalmente indesejável).

Como linguagens de nível mais alto tendem a abstrair a alocação de memória, fica conveniente abdicar ou minimizar o conceito de ponteiro e usar conceitos mais abstratos, como variáveis de referência em C++ (que nem é de tão alto nível assim):

```
void bleah(int &a)
{
  a = 2;
}

void test()
{
  int var = 1;
  bleah(var);
  // neste ponto var tem o valor 2.
}
```

Em C++ uma variável de referência quer dizer "crie um alias (apelido) para o mesmo objeto/variável" em outro escopo.  Se o objeto foi alocado no heap, ou é um inteiro em um registrador que nem endereço de memória tem, pouco importa, tudo isto é abstraído e gerido pelo compilador.

Em C e C++ a passagem de parâmetros para funções por padrão se dá por valor (e o valor poderia ser um ponteiro), e em C++ a variável de referência indica que você quer ter acesso ao mesmo objeto sem precisar copiá-lo, mas *sem explicitar um ponteiro*, provendo um mecanismo específico para passagem de parâmetros para funções por referência.

O "truque" é que você já tem uma variável, que representa um objeto, e a linguagem te permite referenciá-la sem ter que se preocupar com a sua localização.

Então existem dois conceitos aqui, as "variáveis de referência" e "passagem por referência". O primeiro é específico, o segundo é mais geral.

ISO/ANSI C por exemplo não tem uma variável de referência, e a passagem de parâmetros é por valor (ainda que o valor possa ser um ponteiro, e o ponteiro tem a propriedade de *permitir* fazer a referência a um objeto, se ele estiver armazenado em um local na memória).

Em C++, uma variável de referência não tem a sintaxe nem a semântica um ponteiro embora você possa tomar o endereço de uma variável de referência e torná-la em um ponteiro.

Entre ponteiros e variáveis de referência existe ao menos outra substancial diferença: geralmente você precisa ter um objeto do tipo correto já declarado (e frequentemente, já inicializado) para passar por referência. Como você não manipula o endereço, em tese isto evita o uso de ponteiros "selvagens" (cujo valor aponta para o lugar errado, inclusive uma área inexistente, bugs comuns quando se usa ponteiros).

A variável de referência em C# é similar. Se você tentar passar um ponteiro nulo (É possível fazer isto passando código não-gerenciado ou PInvoke) onde ela espera uma referência, a runtime normalmente vai disparar uma Exception. Isto é intencional, pois as referências, via de regra, precisam ser válidas!

Em Java, não há um tipo de "variável de referência". E a passagem de argumentos não se dá por referência, mas pelo *valor da referência*, e isto é quase que totalmente abstraído.

Como você não manipula endereços em Java, toda variável é implicitamente uma variável que armazena uma referência, mas a semântica é outra já que você não acessa a referência, e sim o objeto referenciado.

Quando você passa um objeto java entre funções, está passando "o valor da referência", em uma nova variável. Se você tentar fazer uma função com as do exemplo acima, terá que remover o "&" da declaração do parâmetro, e independentemente do tipo do objeto passado para a função, terá o seguinte comportamento:

```
void bleah(Object a)
{
  // Isto não altera o objeto referenciado por a: faz ela referenciar outro objeto. A variável "a" local não tem nenhuma relação com a variável da função chamadora (a não ser que o valor atribuido a ela originariamente era o mesmo).
  a = new String("b")
}

void test()
{
  Object var = new String("a");
  bleah(var);
  // neste ponto var.toString() ainda retorna "a".
}
```

O que muda é o efeito do operador atribuição: toda variável implicitamente armazena a referencia, mas se você atribuir a uma variável, estará **atribuindo nova referencia**, e não alterando o objeto apontado pela referência anterior. Em C++ você estaria invocando o operador '=' do objeto apontado, em Java isto não acontece, o objeto cuja referência é passado simplesmente não é usado para nada na função acima.

Agora, se ao invés de uma String (que é imutável), você tivesse outro objeto com um método "append" que alterasse suas propriedades e você invocasse o método:

```
void bleah(Weird a)
{
  a.append("whatever");
}
```

Então a função que chamasse bleah enxergaria quaisquer efeitos da chamada a append, pois a referencia a ainda é a mesma. A variável 'a' contem uma referência implícita, mas não é uma "variável de referência" como em C++ pois ela não tenta ser um alias da variável original: a semântica de atribuições é diferente (assim como outras sutilezas).Se passasse por valor, 'a' seria uma cópia do objeto passado, e não o mesmo.

Há linguagens que aceitam variáveis tipo referência (entre as que não aceitam ponteiros, como C#: você não consegue compilar um código com ponteiros em modo "seguro", mas pode usar referências), e há linguagens que não as aceitam;

Há linguagens que fazem a passagem de parâmetros por valor, por referência, pelo valor da referência (!!!) ou algumas combinações das anteriores (como C++ que permite passagem por valor ou por referência, mas esta última de forma explícita).

O conceito abstrato por trás da passagem por referência está em contrapor a passagem por valor: passar um objeto por valor significa passar uma cópia dele. Para um objeto tipo um inteiro ou ponto flutuante ou mesmo um ponteiro, normalmente se passa por valor por questão de performance, já que o custo em copiar o objeto é menor do que manter internamente ponteiros para ele. Mas aí você não pode alterar o valor da variável original (e isto tem muito a ver com a discussão entre funções puras e impuras).

Isto significa que ao passar por cópia, perde-se a referência (!) ao objeto original.Passar uma referência (seja por uma variável de referencia, seja por um ponteiro, seja pelo valor da referencia, como em Java) significa ter como referenciar (ha!) o mesmo objeto e também permite evitar cópias, relevante em objetos grandes ou complexos.

Isto é possível (e mais conveniente) com variáveis tipo referencia, mas Java demonstra que ainda sem ponteiros, elas não são necessárias se a passagem envolver *ao menos* o valor da referência.

Ponteiros são formas de referências a endereços de memória, referências à variáveis ou a objetos podem ser implementadas com ponteiros, eis a confusão.

Answer (score 5):

> **Nota do moderador:** esta resposta foi publicada como uma brincadeira de 1º de abril. Normalmente esse tipo de conteúdo não é aceito no site, mas nessa data específica é feita uma exceção. Passada a data, a publicação foi bloqueada, não podendo mais receber votos nem ser editada. Divirta-se!

Apesar das respostas anteriores serem bastante elucidativas, não posso deixar de
juntar mais uma resposta para melhor clarificar estes importantes conceitos.
Ponteiros e Referências são coisas completamente distintas.

### Ponteiros

(Do Latim Ponte+eiro: fabricante de pontes)

Embora as máquinas actuais tenham reduzido subtancialmente o uso de ponteiros,
estes são ainda de elevada importância.
Há vários tipos de ponteiros (normalmente 2 ou 3 tipos), e nem sempre têm a mesma dimensão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Referências

(Do grego Re+ferir=ferir repetidamente; como refere @bfavaretto há aqui uma
clara relação com o lado pontiagudo dos ponteiros)

[image: ponteiros afiados]

No que diz respeito às linguagens de programação há dois tipos de referência essenciais:

- os manuais de referência (toda a linguagem que se preza deve ter pelo menos um, que por definição, deve evitar falar dos *non-documented features*)
- as cartas de referência (para garantir e atestar a idoneidade co seu autor e a ausência de efeitos laterais perniciosos como sejam, formatar o disco)

### Conclusão

- Como referido pelo OP, linguagens como o Java, recusam a existência de
  ponteiros numa clara referência a que é sempre boa hora para tomar café.
- Algumas operações com ponteiros envolvem muito processador e por vezes problemas de sincronização (ainda este fim se semana
  houve mudança da hora, com a consequente aritmética envolvida)

  (*ponteiro)++
- Para correcto entendimento da resposta sugere-se a execução do seguinte programa
  **`echo lirba 1 aid zilef | rev`**

Comment: Se os ponteiros é que têm pontas, então por que não são eles que ferem repetidamente?

Comment: @bfavaretto, É bem verdadeira e pertinente a observação que levantaste e que vou tentar incluir na resposta. Alguns cientistes referem até as "cicatrizes do tempo" (embora "com tempo tudo se cura"). Está à vontade para melhorar outras incorreções encontradas.

Comment: Até que enfim entendi. Exemplos ilustrados são muito bons, e este aponta claramente os detalhes importantes. Vou guardar como referência.

Comment: @Bacco, muito obrigado. É reconfortante saber que haja quem tire porveito de tão douta resposta envolvendo tanta tecnologia de ponta :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, Nunca pensaram em criar uma medalha de mau comportamento para quem nunca responda do modo que era suposto fazer e que acaba por dar cado da cabeça aos mederadores e ao meta? :)

Comment: Não, mas estamos considerando criar uma pelo bom-humor com pitadas de [imprópria linguagem desbragada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56483/por-que-a-ordem-destes-scanfs-faz-diferen%c3%a7a-no-resultado/56484#comment116204_56484) :)

Comment: Melhor resposta do grupo de sites SE de sempre! :)

Answer (score 0):

Em C++, uma referência é um ponteiro que garantidamente aponta para o objeto do tipo. Por exemplo, A* pode apontar para um objeto A ou pode ser nulo, e pode ser mesmo inválido, já A& é garantido pelo compilador que aponta para um objeto válido.

Java oculta parcialmente os ponteiros (não se pode fazer aritmética de ponteiros com uma referência, nem força-la a apontar para um objeto inválido) mas ainda permite que a referência seja *null*, o que as torna algo parecidas com os ponteiros C++.

Linguagens como Swift e Kotlin permite que se especifique se a referência é anulável. O tipo "A" é uma referência garantidamente válida, já o tipo "A?" pode ser nulo. O programador precisa usar o ponto de exclamação quando quer forçar o uso de uma variável A? como válida.

Answer (score 0):

A diferença entre ponteiro e referência é sutil.

Conceitualmente são dois acessos de indiretos à dados. Tanto ponteiros quanto referência o fazem através de um endereçamento. A diferença é que nas referências esse endereçamento é mais abstrato que no caso dos ponteiros.

Na prática, tanto um quanto o outro são implementados como variáveis inteiras que armazenam o endereço dos dados que realmente se quer. A diferença fica por conta de como os ponteiros e as referências são usadas.

Com ponteiros, o endereço está explícito e o programador "tem acesso" ao endereço, podendo, inclusive, realizar operações sobre estes endereços, como, por exemplo, incrementar ou decrementar a variável apontadora. Exemplos de linguagens que dão suporte à ponteiros: C, C++, Algol, Modula, Pascal etc.

Com referências, o endereço está "oculto" ao programador, que não tem acesso direto a ele e não há operações sobre este endereço. Na verdade há inúmeras operações sobre o endereço, mas são feitas todas indiretamente pelo compilador/máquina virtual que implementa as referências. Por exemplo, em Java, o operador `new` aloca um espaço suficiente e inicializa um objeto, cujo endereço é colocado na variável referência; quando a variável sai do escopo, admite-se que aquele objeto não mais é necessário; o compilador gera código para terminar o objeto (chamar o destrutor) e liberar a memória anteriormente ocupada. Exemplos de linguagens que dão suporte à referências: C++, Java, C# etc.

Referências são uma evolução, em certo sentido, do conceito ponteiros.