# Por que a ordem destes scanf's faz diferença no resultado?

Tags: c, scanf

O programa soma `x1` e `x2` e coloca o resultado em `x1`. Não funciona se `x1` for lido antes de `x2`. Mas se inverter esta ordem, funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char x1,x2;

void soma() {
    x1 = x1 + x2;
}

int main()
{    
    /* Carga das variaveis que estao mapeadas na memoria */
    printf("Valor de x1 = "); scanf("%d", (int*)&x1);
    printf("Valor de x2 = "); scanf("%d", (int*)&x2);
//    printf("Valor de x1 = "); scanf("%d", (int*)&x1);

    soma();

    printf("x1=%d, x2=%d\n", x1, x2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você está curioso porque isto ocorre ou está fazendo algo e está preocupado porque não está dando certo? Você sabe que você está fazendo várias coisas que não deveria fazer em condições normais?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que as suas variáveis são declaradas como `char`, mas você faz a leitura como `int`. Assim, a função `scanf` faz a leitura de mais do que 1 byte e invade a memória da variável `x2` (que como foi declarada depois, está logo em seguida na memória).

Usando o Visual Studio, por exemplo, dá pra perceber que os endereços de memória de cada uma das variáveis é seguido (`x1` em *0x00ff8134* e `x2` em *0x00ff8135*, no meu exemplo, e com 1 byte de diferença já que as variáveis são alocadas como `char`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dai, se você faz a leitura para `x2` antes, dá pra perceber que a função altera 4 bytes (eu compilei para 32 bits).

Antes do `scanf` em `x2`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois do `scanf` em `x2` (com entrada do valor `7`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo vai valer para a leitura para `x1` que você fizer em seguida, só que dai, como a memória é atualizada em 4 bytes, vai ser alterado o valor original de `x2` que vem logo a seguir (***observação***: o endereço de início nas telas a seguir é o da variável `x1`, mas ele não é mais o mesmo de anteriormente porque eu capturei as telas em uma nova execução).

Antes da leitura de um valor para `x1` (com entrada do valor `2`, no meu exemplo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois da leitura de um valor para `x1` (perceba como a área de memória de `x2` foi alterada):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É por esse motivo que a função `scanf` é considerada insegura e seu uso é desaconselhado. Para executar o meu teste, por exemplo, eu tive que usar:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Sem esse define, o próprio compilador (no meu caso, do Visual Studio 2012) aconselha usar [uma alternativa da Microsoft chamada `scanf_s`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434735/difference-between-scanf-and-scanf-s).

Answer (score 6):

`scanf("%d",...)` vai ler e colocar um valor inteiro (exemplo 4 bytes) no endereço que lhe for passado.

Como a variável para onde estás a ler só tem um byte (char), a desgraçada da variável vizinha fica atropelada. Este tipo de coisas pode causar efeitos imprevisíveis (ex, segmentation fault)

Comment: +1 pela "desgracada da variavel vizinha" eheh

Comment: @Omni, obrigado pela compreensão desta minha imprótpria linguagem desbragada :)