# É possível utilizar ponteiros em Java?

Tags: java, ponteiro

Na linguagem C podemos utilizar `ponteiros` da seguinte forma:

```
int *ponteiro, teste;

ponteiro = &teste;
```

E em Java existe alguma alternativa?

Comment: olha @Rafael achei algo interessante https://flaviowbrasil.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/ponteiros-no-java/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma possibilidade de uso de ponteiros brutos em Java. Até mesmo referências tem uso apenas implícito através dos objetos instanciados.

É possível simulá-los através de um *array* de *bytes* mas apenas para demonstração de como funcionaria, dificilmente isto teria um uso prático, e ainda assim não quer dizer que a linguagem tenha ponteiros, apenas que sua semântica pode ser emulada com outras construções.

Isto não quer dizer que o código não use ponteiros internos mas como eles não são expostos de forma alguma para o programador, eles não podem ser considerados como existentes na linguagem. Então existem ponteiros opacos que você não tem acesso.

São raros os casos que eles são úteis - essencialmente por performance, mas realmente é uma pena não tê-los nesses casos. C# os permite em contextos `unsafe` e por isso é possível criar algumas abstrações seguras e obter o melhor dos dois mundos. Em Java se quer usar o ponteiro só fazendo em outra linguagem e não é nada simples.

[Ponteiros X referências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

Tudo em Java que não é primitivo é um objeto, objetos são referenciados por variáveis de referência, de uma forma muito similar aos ponteiros C++.

Ou seja, o que você conhece como ponteiro em C++ é conhecido como referência em Java.

As diferenças não param no nome, a maior diferença na verdade é que no Java você não trabalha diretamente com o endereço de memória, alocação e limpeza da memória alocada. No Java você tem o `new`, mas não tem o `delete`. Isso não quer dizer que a memória alocada ao criar um novo objeto nunca será liberada, esse trabalho é realizado pelo Garbage Collector, que de tempos em tempos limpa os objetos da memória que não possuem mais uma referência válida para eles.

Respondendo sua pergunta: Não é possível ter um ponteiro da mesma forma como no C++, mas é possível ter uma variável de referência que provavelmente suprirá suas necessidades. O Java foi arquitetado de forma diferente do C++, ele é mais alto nível, logo se você precisa trabalhar com acesso diretamente a memória é bem provável que Java **não** será a sua escolha.

Um exemplo de uma criação e instanciação de um objeto em Java:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar um ponteiro em um objeto. 
Por exemplo:

```
Object A = new Object(); //New trata de reservar memória o suficiente para o objeto e criar automaticamente uma referência a ele. 
A.setValue("valor qualquer");
Object B = A;//Aqui o B aponta para o endereço de memória de A
System.out.printf(B.getValue.toString());
//Resultado impresso: valor qualquer

A.setValue("outro valor");
System.out.printf(B.getValue.toString());
//Resultado impresso: outro valor

B.setValue("valor posto por B");
System.out.printf(B.getValue.toString());
//Resultado impresso: valor posto por B
```