# A passagem de objetos em Java simula passagem por referência?

Tags: java, c++

Todo mundo fala que Java passa por valor, inclusive Objetos. Estes são passados por cópia e não é possível reatribuí-los a um novo objeto dentro do método. O problema é que é possível alterar valor de objetos dentro do método. Isso não caracteriza a simulação de passagem por referência (feita com ponteiros em C++)?

**Exemplo de Código Java**

```
class Objeto {

    public int valor;

    public Objeto(){

        this.valor = 2;
    }   
}

public class Passagem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Objeto obj = new Objeto();

        System.out.printf("Valor inicial: %d\n", obj.valor);

        metodo(obj);

        System.out.printf("Valor após o método: %d\n", obj.valor);

        metodoNovo(obj);

        System.out.printf("Valor após o método com novo objeto: %d\n", obj.valor);


    }

    // Simula a passagem por referência alterando o valor do objeto
    // mas não o local de memória para qual aponta
    static void metodo(Objeto obj){

        obj.valor = 5;
    }

    //Tenta alterar o objeto em si
    static void metodoNovo(Objeto obj){

        obj = new Objeto();

        obj.valor = 10;         
    }
}
```

O valor do objeto pode ser diretamente alterado pelo primeiro método. Já na segundo não é possível reatribuir ele a um novo objeto, até mesmo porque o método espera receber um Objeto constante - para alterar um objeto em si a lógica diz que teriamos que ter **um objeto para um objeto**.

O exemplo em C++, que se comporta da mesma maneira:

**Exemplo de Código em C++**

```
#include <iostream> 

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Objeto{

    public:
        int valor;

        Objeto(){

            this->valor = 2;
        }
};

void funcao(Objeto *obj){

    obj->valor = 5;
}

void funcaoNovo(Objeto *obj){

    obj = new Objeto();

    obj->valor = 10;
}

int main()
{
    Objeto *obj = new Objeto();

    cout << "Valor inicial: " << obj->valor << endl;

    funcao(obj);

    cout << "Após função: " << obj->valor << endl;

    funcaoNovo(obj);

    cout << "Após função que atribui novo objeto: " 
        << obj->valor << endl;
}
```

O resultado dos dois códigos é o mesmo.

Só é possível alterar o objeto em si no código C++ se a função esperar receber o endereço do próprio objeto, como em:

**Função C++ que Altera o Objeto**

```
void funcaoNovo(Objeto **obj){

    *obj = new Objeto();

    (*obj)->valor = 10;
}
```

**main para a função acima**

```
int main()
{
    Objeto *obj = new Objeto();

    cout << "Valor inicial: " << obj->valor << endl;

    funcao(obj);

    cout << "Após função: " << obj->valor << endl;

    funcaoNovo(&obj);

    cout << "Após função que atribui novo objeto: " 
        << obj->valor << endl;
}
```

Onde será possível ver que a reatribuição deu certo.

Baseado nessas comparações, **é certo dizer que em Java existe também uma simulação de passagem por referência**? Não é possível alterar o objeto (o local para onde aponta), mas é possível alterar seus valores, pois a função (ou método) chamador altera diretamente o valor dos valores nos objetos.

Nota: Em C também é possível fazer o mesmo teste. Uma dada função `funcao(int *ptr)`
não consegue atribuir o `ptr` a um novo `malloc` dentro dela. Somente o valor pode ser alterado e é considerado uma simulação de passagem por referência.

**Minha maior dúvida:**

Em C++ o objeto em si não altera o valor original.

```
void funcaoNovo(Objeto *obj){

    Objeto *novo = new Objeto();

    novo->valor = 10;

    obj = novo;
 }
```

Aqui o `obj` não é alterado fora da função. Da mesma forma que em Java.

Ou seja não é possível reatribuir um objeto também pois C++ não pode alterar o objeto passado por cópia também. Entretanto **pode alterar o valor contido no objeto** (aqui há a simulação), desde que não tente se alterar o objeto.

Isso é chamado de simulação de passagem por referência, pois a função chamadora modifica os dados contido Objeto e não o Objeto em si. Java não tem passagem por referência (exceto com arrays), mas não seria correto dizer que há uma simulação dessa passagem **no valor para qual o objeto referencia**, ou seja eu consigo uma simulação ao referenciar os valores?

Pois vejo que ambas as passagens são semelhantes - permitem a função alterar valores de fora do escopo (incluindo múltiplos valores), sem permitir a reatribuição do ponteiro (referencia em Java).

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua edição, mas em Java quando se quer modificar objetos inteiros o comum é envolvê-los num "*wrapper*" (um objeto com referência pra outro objeto) e compartilhar esse *wrapper* com todas as partes interessadas. Assim, se uma delas mudar a instância do objeto, as outras obterão o novo objeto ao acessar o *wrapper* (desde que não salvem uma cópia local do objeto em si). Isso é mais ou menos semelhante ao ponteiro para ponteiro, só que um pouco mais limitado.

Comment: Para se alterar um ponteiro, alocando ele em um novo espaço de memória, em C++ (ou C) é preciso exatamente a mesma coisa: um ponteiro para ponteiro. Um ponteiro como parâmetro de função só garante alterar o valor que o objeto (ponteiro) contém (ou para onde aponta), não o objeto em si. Similarmente uma referência em Java, consegue alterar valores, para qual aponta, dentro da função que surtirão efeito fora dela. Da mesma forma que um ponteiro (analogamente à referência) o faz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["Referências"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/215) e ["passagem por referência"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59437/215) são duas coisas distintas. Diferentemente de C/C++, em Java toda variável que se refere a um objeto complexo o faz por meio de uma referência, não um ponteiro e não um tipo valor.

## C/C++

Os três principais meios de se manipular objetos:

```
Objeto valor; // Um objeto no stack
Objeto* ponteiro = &valor; // Um ponteiro para um objeto no stack ou no heap
Objeto& referencia = valor; // Uma referência para um objeto no stack ou no heap
```

A maneira de utilizá-los é diferente: com os tipos valor e as referências, pode-se acessar os membros do objeto diretamente, enquanto com os ponteiros é necessário "derreferenciá-los":

```
cout << "Valor inicial: " << valor.valor << endl;
cout << "Valor inicial: " << (*ponteiro).valor << endl;
cout << "Valor inicial: " << referencia.valor << endl;

// Atalho para ponteiros (derreferenciação e acesso num único operador)
cout << "Valor inicial: " << ponteiro->valor << endl;
```

Ao passá-los para uma função, o tipo valor provoca uma cópia de todo o objeto:

```
void prop1(Objeto arg) {
    arg.valor = 5; // Não afeta o objeto original
}

void redef1(Objeto arg) {
    Objeto novo;
    novo.valor = 10;
    arg = novo; // Não afeta o objeto original
}
```

O ponteiro não copia o objeto, mas como ele simplesmente "aponta" pra algum objeto, mudar seu valor simplesmente o fará apontar para algum outro objeto - não afetando o objeto original:

```
void prop2(Objeto* arg) {
    arg->valor = 5; // Afeta o objeto original
}

void redef2(Objeto* arg) {
    Objeto* novo = new Objeto();
    novo->valor = 10;
    arg = novo; // Não afeta o objeto original
}
```

Já a referência "refere-se" ao objeto original. Qualquer mudança na mesma afetará sim o original, seja mexendo nas suas propriedades, seja reatribuindo-o:

```
void prop3(Objeto& arg) {
    arg.valor = 50; // Afeta o objeto original
}

void redef3(Objeto& arg) {
    Objeto novo;
    novo.valor = 100;
    arg = novo; // Afeta o objeto original
}
```

Alternativa:

```
Objeto& referencia2 = *(new Objeto()); // Uma referência para um objeto no heap

void prop4(Objeto& arg) {
    arg.valor = 50; // Afeta o objeto original
}

void redef4(Objeto& arg) {
    Objeto* novo = new Objeto();
    novo->valor = 100;
    arg = *novo; // Afeta o objeto original
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/yml8wF). **Disclaimer:** não tenho quase nenhuma experiência prática com C/C++, não veja o código acima como uma boa maneira de se programar nessas linguagens (inclusive, tenho quase certeza de que tem ao menos um vazamento de memória nesse código...).

## Java

Em Java, os tipos valor e ponteiros não existem, e uma referência tem algumas coisas em comum com cada um dos três:

- A sintaxe da variável é parecida com a do tipo valor:

  ```
  Objeto referencia;
  ```
- A da construção com a do ponteiro:

  ```
  = new Objeto();
  ```
- E a semântica do resultado final é *parecida* (mas não idêntica) com a da referência:

  ```
  Objeto referencia = new Objeto();
  ```
- Entretanto, **referências são passadas por valor**:

  ```
  void prop(Objeto arg) {
      arg.valor = 5; // Afeta o objeto original
  }

  void redef(Objeto arg) {
      Objeto novo = new Objeto();
      novo.valor = 10;
      arg = novo; // Não afeta o objeto original
  }
  ```

O que isso quer dizer, no final das contas, é que em Java toda variável de um tipo complexo contém não o próprio objeto, mas uma referência (que pode ou não ser implementada através de um ponteiro - ver [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56481/215) para mais detalhes) para o objeto real - que só existe no *heap*. Essa referência pode ser copiada para outras variáveis, o que faz com que elas também passem a referenciar o mesmo objeto.

Acessar um objeto por qualquer uma de suas referências tem o mesmo efeito. Entretanto, as referências em si são independentes umas das outras. Elas são *cópias* umas das outras. E mexer numa cópia não altera a original. É por isso que atribuir um valor a uma referência (i.e. fazê-la apontar para um outro objeto) não tem qualquer efeito nas demais referências para aquele objeto - que continuam apontando para o objeto original.

Comment: "por meio de uma referência, não um ponteiro"  E quando uma referência não é um ponteiro?  Só o açucar sintático do C++ que permite acesso aos membros do objeto sem o uso dos operadores para ponteiro do C. Mas a informação armazenada na variável de referência é a mesma. Acho que sua resposta mais confunde nesse aspecto do que esclarece.

Comment: @jsbueno "quando uma referência não é um ponteiro?" Em Java, nunca! As implementações antigas da JVM (classic e HotSpot) usavam *handles*, que eram um ponteiro fixo para outro ponteiro variável ([fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1574285)). As recentes (Sun/Oracle, não sei quanto às [muitas outras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)) usam ou um tipo chamado `oop` (uma classe que encapsula um ponteiro) ou um chamado `narrowOop`, um inteiro de 32 bits que precisa ser convertido em um ponteiro real antes de acessar um objeto ([fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18135446)).

Comment: "REferencias" e "ponteiros" são dois nomes para a mesma coisa. A diferença entre ambas é que o C++ tem uma sintaxe diferente para lidar com as duas. Enquanto que por limitações historico/técnicas a sintaxe para lidar com dados de uma função tendo em mãos um ponteiro é distinta em C, C++ unifica essa sintaxe, e cria a 'referência'.

Comment: Experimente escrever uma função que aceite dois parâmetros: um ponteiro para uma estrutura, e uma referência para a mesma. faça uma chamada para essa função, passando um ponteiro e uma referência para a _mesma_ estrutura.  Agora abra seu programa com um depurador e veja passo a passo quais são os valores efetivamente passados para a função: do lado de lá chega _o mesmo_ número (um endereço de memória) de 32 ou 64 bit conforme o caso. Ponteiro/referência só faz diferença para a sintaxe necessária para manpulação dos campos.

Comment: @jsbueno Você chegou a testar esse experimento que propôs? Eu poderia fazer isso mas: 1) não tenho tempo, nem disposição, nem estou tão ansioso pra provar que estou correto, já citei várias fontes que corroboram o que eu falo, se quiser contestá-las todas é um direito seu; 2) meu senso comum diz que ele não se comportaria desse jeito - pois se tal função redefinir a referência, a variável externa será afetada, isso está bem visível no exemplo do ideone. Se tudo o que a referência passasse fosse o endereço do referido, como a função alteraria o referente? Isso não faz o menor sentido pra mim.

Comment: Algumas referências (sem trocadilho :P) adicionais: [FAQ do ISO C++ sobre Referências](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references). [Outra pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/520779) que faz uma análise comparativa extensiva da diferença entre esses dois conceitos.

Answer (score 1):

Quase todas as linguagens orientadas a objeto - (se não todas) de fato passam *sempre* os objetos "por referência" - Isso é -tudo o que os métodos ou funções que recebem objetos como parâmetros recebem é uma referência ao objeto original que é normalmente representada internamente por um endereço de memória (um ponteiro) - embora em algumas linguagens de mais alto nível, como Java e Python, ao contrário de C++, o fato de seu método receber um endereço de memória seja tão transparente ao programador a ponto de ser "invisível".

Isso por que quando você acessa atributos ou métodos do objeto, nessas linguagens, a sintaxe é a mesma - ao contrário de C e C++ onde você tem que escrever seu código de um jeito se tem o "valor" da estrutura de dados/objeto ou com outra notação se tem uma "referência".  Na prática é como se nessas linguagens você *sempre* tenha uma referência ao objeto - mesmo no lugar onde ele é declarado e criado.

E por que então você não pode alterar o objeto em si que é referido? Por que o *nome* da variável que recebe o objeto  está na função ou método alvo - e aponta para um objeto específico. Se você aponta o nome para um outro objeto, o método que chamou seu código não tem como saber disso.  Por outro lado, se você faz alterações no objeto recebido, está de fato alterando o mesmíssimo objeto que quem chamou o método atual está "vendo".

Na verdade, fora de C, nem faz muito sentido você ficar se preocupando se está passando por "referência" ou "valor" na maior parte do tempo - vocẽ precisa saber que está passando um objeto de um lado para o outro.

Comment: Boa resposta, só discordo que a distinção seja irrelevante fora de C/C++ - C# é uma linguagem moderna, e ela emprega essa distinção em alguns casos (ex.: `Struct`s são um objeto complexo mas são um "tipo-valor", e portanto sua passagem acarreta numa cópia; existem também o `ref` e o `out` que pelo que eu saiba [pouco; não tenho experiência com C#] modificam a forma de passagem).

Comment: Bom, também não conheço C#, mas ele não se desvincula completamente de C e C++ (nem no nome) - se ele insiste em tornar endereços de memória menos transparentes, como você coloca, é mais um reflexo dessa herança. (que não digo que não possa acarretar ganhos de performance em algumas construções específicas, mas as custas da facilidade de uso da linguagem)

Comment: Ao contrário da sua primeira afirmação, em Java, C#, Delphi, Ruby, VB.Net... o padrão é passar o argumento por valor, e não por referência; e Java sequer suporta a passagem de argumentos por referência (em Java todo argumento, independentemente do seu tipo, é sempre passado por valor). Há que se ter em mente que *"tipos por valor e tipos por referência"* é diferente de *"passagem por valor e passagem por referência"*. Os links citados na resposta do @mgibsonbr esclarecem isso.

Comment: Caffé: não conheço tão bem as outras linguagens, mas Java **com certeza** não duplica todo objeto passado por um método - que é o principal "side effect" de "passagem por valor".

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo passagem por referência com a necessidade de uso de operadores especiais para acessar os campos de um objeto na função chamada.

Comment: Java não duplica objetos, mas duplica **referências**. C/C++ também duplicam ponteiros, quando os mesmos são passados por valor. Isso é algo que eu próprio não entendia bem, até iniciarmos essas discussões (esta pergunta e mais as duas que eu linkei), mas agora está bastante claro pra mim: passar um ponteiro pra uma função **não é** passagem por referência, e sim passagem por valor. Só que é *o ponteiro* que é passado por valor, não *a coisa para a qual ele aponta*. Por isso não duplica os objetos em si. Mas chame 100 funções passando um ponteiro, e 100 cópias *desse ponteiro* serão feitas.