# Qual a diferença entre "passagem por valor" e "passagem por referência"?

Tags: java, c#, c, passagem-por-referência, passagem-por-valor

Sei que em no primeiro o objeto passado como argumento para uma função é copiado, e no segundo não. Também sei que é extremamente incomum em linguagens modernas a passagem de objetos complexos por valor, enquanto tipos primitivos (números, caracteres, booleanos...) frequentemente o são. Mas o que exatamente são esses modos de passagem? Leio muito que "em Java as referências são passadas por valor", e vejo também que há linguagens modernas (como C#) que dão mais opções de passagem de parâmetros que a maioria das linguagens Orientadas por Objeto.

O que gostaria que fosse explicado é:

- "Na passagem por valor o argumento é copiado." OK, mas **o que exatamente** é copiado? O objeto inteiro, inclusive todas as suas referências?
- O que constitui uma passagem por referência? Se a linguagem possui ponteiros, passar um ponteiro para um objeto como argumento significa que se está passando o objeto por referência?
- O que significa exatamente "passar uma referência por valor"? (volta aqui o primeiro item - *o que* da referência está sendo copiado, já que a passagem é por valor?)

Para não ficar muito amplo (se é que já não está), peço que as respostas se foquem nas linguagens C/C++ (tradicionais, que introduziram a muitos de nós os conceitos envolvidos), Java (que pelo menos pra mim marcou a mudança de paradigma entre raciocinar em termos de ponteiros e em termos de referências) e talvez C# (linguagem moderna que se não me engano trouxe mais flexibilidade nas formas de manipular objetos).

Comment: Senti falta de uma pergunta no SOpt explicando esses dois conceitos. A [pergunta equivalente no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/520779) possui algumas boas respostas, que podem servir de inspiração pra quem for responder.

Comment: Depende do que você quer dizer com valor, o valor para qual o ponteiro aponta ou o próprio valor do ponteiro. `funcao(int *ptr)` passa o ponteiro `ptr` por valor e o valor para o qual ele aponta por referência. Já `funcao(int **ptr)` passa o próprio ponteiro por referência.

Comment: Resposta perigosa, já que muitas pode ser feito de maneira diferente de uma linguagem para outra.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Introdução: *TIPOS* por valor/referência versus *PASSAGEM* por valor/referência

Muito da resistência dos programadores em aceitar uma explicação sobre ***passagem* por valor/referência** vem da confusão que fazem com ***tipos* por valor/referência**, mas são coisas completamente distintas. Então segue uma breve introdução sobre tipos por valor/referência:

#### Tipos por valor

Falando em alto nível, sem entrar no mérito da gestão da memória ou detalhes de implementação das linguagens/plataformas, podemos dizer sem medo de errar que uma variável inicializada sempre contém um valor:

```
int X = 1;
```

*Integer* é um tipo por valor. Uma variável de tipo por valor armazena o valor nela própria. No código acima, portanto, a variável *X* contém o valor 1.

#### Tipos por referência

Agora considere o código abaixo:

```
String Y = "1";
```

*String* é um tipo por referência. A variável *Y*, assim como a variável *X*, também contém um valor, mas o valor da variável *Y* não é "1"! O valor da variável *Y* é uma referência para um objeto string.

Outra forma de dizer: a variável *Y* não armazena o valor atribuído a ela mas sim uma referência para este valor, o qual está em algum outro lugar por aí na memória.

Uma analogia* comum é dizer que uma variável de um tipo por referência contém o endereço do valor ou o endereço do objeto que representa o valor, em vez de conter o próprio valor. Mas este endereço, por si só, também é um valor (em alguns aspectos).

<sub>*Analogia** porque em várias linguagens, como Java e C#, a referência não pode ser manipulada como um endereço ou um ponteiro de verdade poderiam ser.</sub>

> Desde que haja suporte na linguagem, um objeto por referência pode ser passado tanto por valor quanto por referência; e um objeto por valor também pode ser passado tanto por valor quanto por referência.

O restante da resposta vai demonstrar isso e vai demonstrar também que:

> O tipo do objeto (seja por valor ou por referência) não afeta a maneira como ele vai ser passado por parâmetro (se por valor ou por referência), mas pode afetar os efeitos que a interação com este parâmetro pode causar no objeto.

Para tentar evitar confusão, o restante da resposta chama os tipos por valor de "tipos primitivos", e os tipos por referência de "tipos complexos", que é como eles são conhecidos em algumas comunidades.

## Diferença entre passagem por valor e passagem por referência

A definição mais simples e de alto nível que consigo pensar, é:

> Na passagem por **valor**, é passada uma cópia do valor da variável.
>
> Na passagem por **referência**, é passada uma referência à própria variável.

Isso é verdade independetemente do tipo da variável.

Ou seja, **não importa se o tipo de uma variável é primitivo ou complexo, a afirmação acima é sempre verdadeira**.

Veja este código (válido tanto em C# quanto em Java) onde passamos um argumento por valor:

```
void metodoQualquer(int parametro1) {
    parametro1 = 26;
}
...
int meuNumeroFavorito = 13;
metodoQualquer(meuNumeroFavorito);
//aqui, *meuNumeroFavorito* permanece 13.
```

No código acima, *metodoQualquer* recebeu uma **cópia do valor** de *meuNumeroFavorito*, então quando ele alterou este valor, ele estava alterando uma cópia e não afetou o valor da variável *meuNumeroFavorito*.

Agora veja este código (válido em C# mas não em Java) onde passamos um argumento por referência:

```
void metodoQualquer(ref int parametro1) {
    parametro1 = 26;
}
...
int meuNumeroFavorito = 13;
metodoQualquer(ref meuNumeroFavorito);
//aqui, *meuNumeroFavorito* agora é 26!
```

No código acima, *metodoQualquer* recebeu uma **referência à variável** *meuNumeroFavorito*, então ele alterou o valor da própria variável em vez de alterar uma cópia do seu valor.

Este código é válido em C# mas não em Java porque **Java não suporta passagem por referência**.

## Passando tipos complexos por valor

O comportamento observado quando passamos tipos complexos por valor confunde algumas pessoas.

Vamos ver um objeto complexo sendo passado por valor:

```
void metodoQualquer(Objeto parametro1) {
    parametro1.atributo = 26;
}
...
Objeto meuNumeroFavorito = new Objeto();
meuNumeroFavorito.atributo = 13;
metodoQualquer(meuNumeroFavorito);
//aqui, *meuNumeroFavorito.atributo* agora é 26.
```

Então eu passei um argumento **por valor** e as alterações feitas neste argumento são percebidas na variável original.

Isso ocorre porque uma variável de tipo complexo contém uma referência ao objeto. A palavra "referência" aqui tem outro sentido. Podemos dizer que referência, neste contexto, é o endereço de memória onde o objeto reside de fato. Então a variável contém na verdade um endereço de memória, e se formos até este endereço vamos encontrar lá o nosso objeto.

Quando eu passo esta variável como argumento para o *metodoQualquer*, já que o argumento foi passado **por valor**, foi feita uma cópia do conteúdo da variável - este conteúdo é a referência para o objeto, ou seja, o seu endereço. E agora cada variável contém uma cópia do endereço do mesmo objeto. De modo que ao alterar os atributos deste objeto através de uma destas variáveis, o efeito será percebido ao acessar o objeto pela outra variável.

```
    meuNumeroFavorito -> contém o endereço #B5F67
    parametro1        -> contém o endereço #B5F67

    No endereco de memória #B5F67, reside o objeto para o qual ambas as variáveis apontam.
```

### E o struct?

Em C# temos *structs*, que assim como *int* também é um *tipo por valor*, que é o que eu venho generalizando nesta resposta como *tipo primitivo*.

<sub>Em C#, tipo "primitivo" e "complexo" pode se tornar uma nomenclatura simplista demais, uma vez que todos os tipos herdam de *object* e eu posso declarar tipos do mesmo jeito que os tais primitivos são declarados, usando *struct*.</sub>

Uma variável do tipo de um *struct* não contém uma referência (ou endereço) para um objeto mas contém sim o seu valor de fato, então quando passamos um *struct* por valor, o próprio *struct* é copiado.

Veja o código C# abaixo:

```
struct MeuInteiro
{
    public int atributo;
}
...
void MetodoQualquer(MeuInteiro meuInteiro)
{
    meuInteiro.atributo = 26;
}
...
var meuInteiro = new MeuInteiro();
meuInteiro.atributo = 13;
MetodoQualquer(meuInteiro);
// aqui, *meuInteiro.atributo* permanece 13!
```

O valor do atributo do struct passado por valor foi modificado dentro do método e esta modificação não foi percebida fora do método. Isso porque foi feita, digamos assim, uma cópia completa do *struct* ao passá-lo por valor. São copiadas inclusive as referências que o struct possua para outros objetos complexos.

Se no código acima eu apenas mudar a declaração *struct MeuInteiro* para *class MeuInteiro*, o resultado será diferente - depois da execução de *MetodoQualquer* o valor de *meuInteiro.atributo* terá sido modificado para *26*.

## Passando tipos complexos por referência

Ao passar um tipo complexo por referência, eu não passo o endereço do objeto mas sim uma referência à variável que está sendo passada como argumento. E então eu posso alterar o endereço contido nesta variável de modo a fazê-la apontar para outro objeto completamente distinto.

Como eu já disse, Java suporta apenas passagem por valor, de modo que o código abaixo só é válido em C#:

```
void metodoQualquer(ref Objeto parametro1) {
    parametro1 = new Objeto();
}
...
Objeto meuNumeroFavorito = new Objeto();
metodoQualquer(ref meuNumeroFavorito);
//aqui, *meuNumeroFavorito* agora aponta (ou "referencia") outro objeto completamente distinto.
```

## Respostas diretas às suas perguntas

> Na passagem por valor o argumento é copiado. OK, mas o que exatamente é copiado? O objeto inteiro, inclusive todas as suas referências?

Em Java e C#, se "objeto" é de um tipo primitivo, de fato ele é copiado quando passado por valor. Se ele é de um tipo complexo, o objeto em si não é copiado - o que é copiado é a referência para o objeto (ou o "endereço" do objeto).

Se for passado um objeto e esse objeto possui referências para outros, estas outras referências não são copiadas:

```
void metodoQualquer(Objeto parametro1) {
    parametro1.atributo = null;
    parametro1 = null;
}
...
Objeto argumento = new Objeto();
argumento.atributo = new OutroObjeto();
metodoQualquer(argumento);
//aqui, *argumento* manteve sua referênia ("endereço") para a mesma instância de Objeto
//e *argumento.atributo* agora é null.
```

O código acima demonstra que, na passagem de um tipo complexo por valor, a referência ao objeto é copiada mas as referências que ele possui não são. (Exceção aos *structs* do C#, explicados na sua sessão específica).

> O que constitui uma passagem por referência?

Constitui passar uma referência à própria variável que se está passando como argumento. Não confundir esta "referência" com uma referência a um objeto na memória.

> Se a linguagem possui ponteiros, passar um ponteiro para um objeto como argumento significa que se está passando o objeto por referência?

Não, o ponteiro pode ser passado tanto por valor quanto por referência.

Veja: você passa um ponteiro para um objeto. Se você passar este argumento por valor, o ponteiro está sendo copiado. Se você passar este argumento por referência, você está passando uma referência à sua variável original, e o ponteiro contido nela pode ser mudado dentro do método de modo a apontar para outro objeto.

> O que significa exatamente "passar uma referência por valor"? O que da referência está sendo copiado, já que a passagem é por valor?

O que está sendo copiado é a própria referência ao objeto e apenas ela. Podemos dar outro nome para esta referência que está sendo copiada - podemos chamá-la de "endereço". Assim, o que está sendo copiado é o endereço do objeto e não o objeto em si.

## Conclusão

- Na passagem por valor, é passada uma cópia do valor da variável.
- Na passagem por referência, é passada uma referência à própria variável.
- O tipo da variável (se "primitivo" ou "complexo") não tem nenhuma relação com o fato de que ela será passada por valor ou por referência.
- Quando um método manipula uma variável de tipo primitivo passada por valor, esta manipulação não é percebida fora do método.
- Quando um método manipula os atributos de uma variável de tipo complexo passada por valor, esta manipulação é percebida fora do método.
- Java suporta apenas passagem por valor.
- C# suporta passagem por valor e por referência.
- Em Java e C#, não é feita nenhuma cópia do objeto de tipo complexo ao passá-lo por valor. O que é copiada é a referência ao objeto (ou o "endereço" do objeto).

Answer (score 12):

> "Na passagem por valor o argumento é copiado." OK, mas o que exatamente é copiado? O objeto inteiro, inclusive todas as suas referências?

O que é copiado é exatamente o valor que foi passado como argumento. Esse valor pode ser um primitivo, pode ser um objeto, pode ser um ponteiro (um endereço de memória) ou pode ser uma referência a um objeto (como o valor de uma variável que aponta para um objeto, como qualquer variável que contenha um objeto em Java). Se for passado um objeto e esse objeto possui referências para outros, não é feita uma cópia profunda do objeto, e sim uma cópia das referências que ele contém (pelo menos nas linguagens que conheço, e considerando que a linguagem permita a passagem direta de um objeto, por valor).

> O que constitui uma passagem por referência? Se a linguagem possui ponteiros, passar um ponteiro para um objeto como argumento significa que se está passando o objeto por referência?

Estritamente falando, passar um ponteiro não constitui passagem por referência. Tenha em mente que [referência é algo mais abstrato que ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56481/74), é um conceito, e pode tanto ser usado para explicar uma funcionalidade (nas linguagens que formalmente implementam uma "passagem por referência"), quanto um comportamento (nas que não implementam isso mas permitem fazê-lo de outras maneiras).

Em C, por exemplo, não existe "passagem por referência". Se você passa um ponteiro, o que é passado é uma cópia do endereço de memória onde está o objeto, e esse endereço é guardado num novo ponteiro com escopo local na função. Dependendo do que você faz com esse ponteiro, pode ou não obter o mesmo comportamento de uma passagem por referência:

- Se você altera o valor do ponteiro (o endereço que ele guarda), o objeto original não é afetado, ao contrário do que ocorreria um uma passagem por referência.
- Se você desreferencia o ponteiro e altera o valor guardado no endereço que ele registra, o comportamento é equivalente ao de uma passagem por referência.

> O que significa exatamente "passar uma referência por valor"? (volta aqui o primeiro item - o que da referência está sendo copiado, já que a passagem é por valor?)

Passar uma referência por valor é bem diferente de passar um valor por referência! Para explicar isso, pense em uma variável qualquer que contenha um objeto. Por exemplo, em Java:

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
```

A variável `bar` contém uma referência a uma instância de `Foo`. Essa instância tem uma identidade própria, cuja representação é até mesmo exposta pela linguagem se você pedir um `bar.hashCode()`. Pode haver múltiplas referências a esse mesmo objeto:

```
Foo baz = bar; // cria uma CÓPIA da referência, apontando pra o mesmo objeto
```

Ao passar esse objeto para uma função, ocorre o mesmo que na atribuição acima: cria-se uma cópia da referência. A referência tem um valor, e esse valor representa uma maneira de se encontrar o objeto na memória (provavelmente envolvendo ponteiros, mas isso é detalhe de implementação – no caso do Java, da implementação da JVM). É esse valor que é copiado quando uma referência é passada por valor. Alterar esse valor não altera outras referências com valor igual. Você pode manipular o objeto para o qual a referência aponta, porém se atribuir algo diretamente à referência, o objeto não é afetado.

Já uma passagem por referência manipula diretamente aquilo que é referenciado. Se um objeto é passado por referência e a variável que representa essa referência é nulificada, o objeto deixa de existir.

Answer (score -1):

Em resumo , passagem por valor não altera o resultado da variavel (antes da passagem ser efetuada) sendo assim menos economica em termos de gasto de memoria.

Já a passagem por referência , o programa vai alterar diretamente o valor de um endereço de memoria especifico.