# Comportamento dos parâmetros no construtor da classe em C#

Tags: c#, .net, parâmetros, referência

Estou com uma duvida em relação ao comportamento dos parâmetros passados para o construtor de uma classe, eles são por *default* `ref`/`out` ou valor? Pesquisando sobre o comportamento dos parâmetros em métodos comuns eles são por padrão valores, como diz esse exemplo:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/parameter

Mas quando eu criei esse exemplo, percebo que o que eu faço fora do escopo da classe altera o estado da propriedade da instancia, que é privada. Está correto isso?

```
public class escopo
{
    public void Controller()
    {
        var lista = CriarLista();
        var teste = new teste(lista);

        lista[0] = "Example";

        teste.testeVeridico();
    }

    public List<String> CriarLista()
    {
        var lista = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
        return lista;
    }
}

public class teste
{
    private List<String> Lista { get; set; }

    public teste(List<String> lista)
    {
        Lista = lista;
    }

    public bool testeVeridico()
    {
        //retorna true
        return Lista[0] == "Example";
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta resposta sobre passagem de parâmetro por valor ou por referência deve lhe ser útil: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59687/14584

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os parâmetros são por valor. Pelo menos este é o padrão. Mas o tipo de dado dele influencia seu comportamento. Você tem [tipos que são por valor e tipos que são por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Não confunda passagem de parâmetro com a forma de alocação dos tipos. Passar por valor não é a mesma coisa que ter um tipo por valor.

Passar por valor significa que uma cópia do dado é feita.

Os tipos por valor fazem o que você espera já que há a cópia do dado que você enxerga.

Os tipos por referência também são passados por valor. Mas qual é o valor dos tipos por referência? É um ponteiro para um objeto no *heap*. É um endereço de memória. Sempre. Então a cópia é feita também, mas é o endereço que é copiado, e não o objeto referenciado. É por valor também.

A diferença é que este tipo tem um objeto com um tempo de vida maior. Internamente o valor é ponteiro, mas no seu código você acessa este objeto apontado por ele. Qualquer alteração nele, reflete no objeto em todo seu tempo de vida, mesmo fora do método onde houve a alteração. Isto é uma característica do tipo e não da passagem do parâmetro.

Note que se você mudar o endereço do objeto, aí você verá que não houve esta [alteração no argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) passado para o método, seja construtor ou não.

Criei um exemplo para demonstrar isto:

```
public void OutroTeste(List<string> lista) {
    lista = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb" };
    return;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GJDGNQ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FNVkOV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ConstructorParameter.cs).

Este método está recebendo `lista` por valor. Em seguida ele cria uma **nova** lista com dados completamente diferentes dentro dela e mando guardar em `lista` que é o parâmetro. Quando eu for acessar a lista depois que executei este método, o que acontece? Estes dados novos sumiram. A nova lista só existe dentro do método, mesmo eu tendo atribuído ela para o parâmetro, ele não foi alterado, porque desta vez eu alterei de fato o parâmetro. Quando você altera os elementos da mesma lista que o parâmetro aponta, você está alterando o objeto apontado e não o parâmetro em si.

[Saiba mais sobre a alocação deles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

No seu exemplo `List<T>` é um tipo por referência, é uma classe. Então tudo o que você alterar nele, se refletirá na variável que foi usada como argumento.

Um tipo curioso é o `string`. Ele é uma referência, então sempre é passado o ponteiro. Mas é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) e possui semântica de valor, então uma mudança no objeto criará um novo objeto que será alocado em outra posição de memória. Portanto a alteração ficará restrita ao método onde isto ocorreu. A não ser, é claro que o parâmetro seja marcado como referência.

## Parâmetros `ref`

[`out` e `ref` servem para passar por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101). Aí sempre passará uma referência, para o real valor. No caso dos tipos por referência, haverá uma referência para o ponteiro do tipo que não deixa de ser uma referência para o objeto propriamente dito. Neste caso até no exemplo acima se um novo objeto for criado, isto se refletirá fora do método.

Portanto tipos por valor ou tipos por referência podem fazer uso da passagem por referência.

Se tiver curiosidade de entender melhor [como funciona a *stack* e o *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Comment: Valeu cara, muito bem explicado. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a confusão esta em Tipos Primitivos e Objetos...

## Tipos Primitivos

Parâmetros de tipos primitivos (int, string, bool e etc...) são sempre passados como valores, por exemplo:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String tipoString = "Valor do Tipo Primitivo";
        Int32 tipoInt = 50;

        //Alterações nos valores?
        MetodoString(tipoString);
        MetodoInt(tipoInt);

        Console.WriteLine(tipoString); // Valor do Tipo Primitivo
        Console.WriteLine(tipoInt); // 50
    }

    static void MetodoString(String aParametro)
    {
        //Neste caso esta mudança apenas e valida neste escopo
        //Pois o parametro do tipo String e passado como Valor
        aParametro = "Mudança de Valor";
    }

    static void MetodoInt(Int32 aParametro)
    {
        //O mesmo ocorre neste caso
        aParametro = 10;
    }
```

Como visto acima tanto o valor de String como o Inteiro não sofreram mudanças quando passados por parâmetro. Isto ocorre porque durante a passagem do parâmetro e feito uma copia do valor da String "tipoString".

Agora com objetos a historia muda um pouco...

## Objetos

Parâmetros de objetos como por exemplo (Listas, Controles, Classes Criadas por Você mesmo!) são passadas através por **Referencia**.

Como assim Referencia?

Quando passada uma lista por parâmetro não e feita uma copia de todos os valores dela, porem e passado apenas um endereço apontando para ela, ou seja, apenas uma referencia! por exemplo:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> listaString = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C" };

        //Alterações nos valores?
        MetodoString(listaString);

        //Comando que impirmi todos os valores da Lista
        listaString.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f)); // A
                                                        // B
                                                        // C
                                                        // D
    }

    static void MetodoString(List<String> aParametroLista)
    {
        //Neste caso É adicionado o valor D na lista pois o Parametro "aParametroLista"
        //Apenas aponta pra minha real lista
        aParametroLista.Add("D");
    }
```

Como visto acima no caso dos objetos quando passados por parâmetro são afetados pelo escopo do método.

Mas será sempre assim? Tipos primitivos sempre serão passados por valor e objetos por referencia?

A resposta é não!

## Ref

Podemos passar parâmetros de tipos primitivos por referencia utilizando por exemplo o comando ref:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String tipoString = "Valor do Tipo Primitivo";

        //Alterações nos valores?
        MetodoString(ref tipoString);

        Console.WriteLine(tipoString); // Mudança de Valor
    }

    static void MetodoString(ref String aParametro)
    {
        // Neste caso o valor do parametro Será mudado pois isto é uma Referencia!
        // ou seja apenas um endereço
        aParametro = "Mudança de Valor";
    }
```

Como visto acima neste caso ate mesmo valores primitivos podem ser passados por referencia.

Caso fique interessado nessas Referencias... Pesquise sobre áreas de memoria como Stack e Heap

Dica de pesquisa: [O que são e onde estão o “stack” e “heap”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap)

Espero ter ajudado! Bons Estudos

Comment: Você é programador Java, né? Embora a resposta não esteja essencialmente errada, em C# é um pouco diferente do que você respondeu. São apenas detalhes, mas a terminologia usada é toda que é usada no Java, exceto o `ref`, obviamente. E faço um adendo sobre o último exemplo. Não está mudando o valor da *string*, está criando uma nova. O tipo *string* tem valor por referência )i que você chamou de objeto) mas por ser [imutável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) tem semântica como se fosse por valor (o que você chamou de primitivo).

Comment: @bigown na verdade a resposta está sim essencialmente errada pois ela diz que parâmetros listas, controles, e classes do usuário são passadas por referência, mas **no C# esses parâmetros, por padrão, são passados por valor**; e **no java eles sempre são passados por valor** pois o Java sequer suporta passagem de parâmetro por referência. Como de praxe, há uma confusão aqui entre "tipos referência" e "passagem de parâmetro por referência". Esta resposta detalha um pouco mais: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59687/14584

Comment: @Caffé você tem razão nisto, não tinha me atentado a esse parágrafo da resposta. De qualquer forma eu não gostei da resposta como um todo, mas estava querendo não parecer agressivo. Acho que você já leu as minhas respostas que eu falo muito sobre essas diferenças. Vou até editar minha resposta para deixar isto mais claro.