# Variável fica com outro valor mesmo sem atribuir valores à ela

Tags: java, variáveis

Eu chamo um JFrame passando como parâmetro minha variável e lá eu atribuo ela em outra variável que declarei para poder fazer as operações necessárias. Mas quando eu fecho o **JFrame 2** a minha variável do **JFrame 1** fica com os mesmos valores.

Como isso pode ocorrer se eu não retorno nada?

```
// Aqui utilizo o método get do recipesTableModel para obter minha variável (Ingredient.class)
ViewDatasheetJFrame frame2 = new ViewDatasheetJFrame(recipesTModel.get(row));
frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(rootPane);
frame2.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito bem nem pela explicação e nem pelo código. Experimente mostrar mais do código relacionado. Veja se isso ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59437/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-passagem-por-valor-e-passagem-por-refer%c3%aancia

Comment: @Caffé Acho que é realmente isso. Porque no Frame 2 eu troco os valores dos meus atributos e quando volto para o Frame 1 percebo que os valores estão trocados também. No post que você mandou percebi isso quando ele fala sobre "Passando tipos complexos por valor".

Comment: Legal, que bom que minha resposta lá foi útil ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi discutido nos comentários, a resposta deste post se encontra em outro que está falando sobre [passagem por valor e por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59437/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-passagem-por-valor-e-passagem-por-refer%C3%AAncia).