# Variável como argumento de método Java

Tags: java, variáveis, parâmetros

Tem como passar uma variável como argumento de um método, não o seu valor, mas a instancia em si, toda mudança feita no argumento se aplica a variável, assim como funciona em JavaScript?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre "passagem por valor" e "passagem por referência"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59437/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-passagem-por-valor-e-passagem-por-refer%C3%AAncia)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim e não. Vamos conceituar bem.

A [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) não pode ser passada, ela é um conceito local que indica armazenamento de alguma coisa. A instância pode sim.

Em tipos por valor a variável contém a própria instância. Em tipos por referência é passado um ponteiro que aponta para uma instância (tecnicamente o ponteiro não deixa de ser uma instância também, mas não do objeto principal).

Tipos por referência costumam permitir que seus dados sejam alterados e quando o método é finalizado as alterações se refletirão na variável original usada como argumento. Mas não é garantido que seja assim. Alguns tipos, [chamados imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), podem criar uma nova instância (`String`).

Todas as classes que tem seus valores passados como argumento se comportarão assim, igual ao JavaScript faz com seus objetos.

Mas note que, assim como JavaScript, Java tem tipos por valor que são copiados e mudanças nele não se refletirão na variável usada.

Java tem a "vantagem" de ter classes equivalentes aos primitivos. Então se quer passar um, passe um `Integer` no lugar de um `int`.

Se passar uma `String`, que é uma classe, mas que tem semântica de tipo por valor, igual ao JavaScript, e alguma alteração for feita nela, o código não verá as alterações feitas no final do código do método, já que não é o objeto que foi alterado, outro objeto foi criado e apontado para ele na variável local (parâmetro). O argumento não é alterado, o consumidor não verá nada feito dentro do método. A única solução em caso assim é envelopar (encaixotar) em um outro tipo por referência, assim o ponteiro da *string* é enviado por referência e será alterado no argumento.

```
void exemplo(int x) { x = 1; } //quem chamar este método não terá seu valor mudado para 1
void exemplo(Integer x) { x = 1; } //quem chamar este método terá seu valor mudado para 1
void exemplo(String x) { x = "x"; } //quem chamar não terá seu valor mudado para "x"
void exemplo(MinhaClasse x) { x.setNome("João"); } //o campo nome será mudado
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Reference.java).

Não é a mesma linguagem, mas pode ter uma ideia melhor de como funciona em:

- [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)