# Qual a diferença entre as 2 passagens de parâmetro?

Tags: visualg

Existe a passagem de parâmetro por valor e por referência. Queria exemplos para compreender melhor a diferença.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59687/51124) você encontra a diferença detalhada entre “passagem por valor” e “passagem por referência”.

Em resumo e com [exemplos](http://www.eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem4.htm) em VisuAlg, a passagem por valor são feitas apenas cópias dos valores das variáveis passadas como parâmetro.

```
funcao soma (x,y: inteiro): inteiro
inicio
retorne x + y
fimfuncao

No programa principal deve haver os seguintes comandos:
n <- 4
m <- -9
res <- soma(n,m)
escreva(res)
```

Já a passagem por referência modifica a variável que você passa como parâmetro.

```
procedimento soma (x,y: inteiro; var result: inteiro)
inicio
result <- x + y
fimprocedimento

No programa principal deve haver os seguintes comandos:
n <- 4
m <- -9
soma(n,m,res)
escreva(res)
```

Exemplos retirados de: [A Linguagem de Programação do VisuAlg](http://www.eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem4.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A passagem de valor por referência torna-se uma característica que oferece mais dinâmica, ou seja, você está dizendo ao compilador onde está o valor e não informando o valor propriamente dito, referindo-se a uma variável por exemplo, seria onde ela está armazenada na memória. O oposto seria a passagem de parâmetro por valor, onde você simplesmente diz que 'variável x equivale a 10'.