# Dúvida ao utilizar variáveis

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float valor;

    printf("...");
    scanf("%f", &valor);
    printf("%0.2f", valor);
}
```

Em scanf devo fazer referência ao ponteiro (espaço de memória), já em printf essa referência não é válida. Qual a explicação mais coerente?

Comment: C não tem referência.

Comment: Quando você passa `valor` ao `printf`, você está passando o conteúdo da variável (que é exatamente o que essa função precisa, já que a tarefa dela é imprimir esse valor). Já para a função `scanf` não adiantaria passar um valor, o que ela precisa é de um lugar para armazenar o valor que o usuário informar. Ela precisa de um endereço de memória para fazer isso, por isso recebe um ponteiro. Isso porque em C os argumentos são sempre [passados por valor](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59437).

Comment: Duvida esclarecida. Obrigado. Por fim, em C, este símbolo tem algum nome em especial?

Comment: Esse operador `&` se chama "address-of".