# Valores das variáveis não são trocados dentro do método

Tags: java

Não entendi por que o programa exibe, no último `System.out.print`, isso:

```
2 5 2 4 6 8 10
```

Em vez disso:

```
5 2 5 10 15 20 25
```

O primeiro método, `trocaB`, não deveria trocar os valores das variáveis `a` e `b`?

```
public class Java {  
 public static void trocaB(String a, String b){  
  String tmp = a;  
  a = b;  
  b = tmp;  
 }  
 public static void trocaC(int[] array, String a){      
  for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){  
   array[x] = array[x] * Integer.valueOf(a);
  }  
 }  
 public static void main(String[] args){  
  int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};  
  String a = "2", b="5";  
  trocaB(a, b);  
  trocaC(array,a);  
  System.out.print(a + " " + b + " ");  
  for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
   System.out.print(array[x] + " ");
  }    
 }  
}
```

Comment: Senhores(as), me perdoem a pergunta idiota, estou aprendendo Java ainda. Agradeço profundamente por me ajudarem com os links. Compreendi que os valores das Strings são imutáveis e que as variáveis complexas guardam endereços dos objetos aos quais se referenciam. Entretanto, no método trocaB, eu digo que a variável complexa A, a partir daquele momento, se referenciará à variável complexa B. Por que não muda o valor de A?? Isso não deveria fazer a variável A guardar um novo endereço?

Comment: Leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59430/112052), principalmente a parte final sobre Java que diz que referências são passadas por valor. Destaque para o último parágrafo: "referências em si são independentes umas das outras. Elas são cópias umas das outras. E mexer numa cópia não altera a original"