# Retornar dois valores usando o return

Tags: java

Sobre a divisão de um programa em métodos, em um caso de um método que execute duas funções ao mesmo tempo (valor e tamanho total) como eu faço para usar o return nos dois valores? Ambos devem ser executados em conjunto, não vejo possibilidade de dividir este método em dois (um para o valor e um para o tamanho)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sistema_Bichara{
    public static int Menu(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o o número referente ao tamanho da pulseira\n1.Pequena (17cm) - R$180,00\n2.Média (18cm) - R$200,00\n3.Grande (20cm) - R$240,00\n4.Sair");
        int digita = in.nextInt();
        return digita;
    }
    public static double valorPulseira(int digita){
        double valor = 0;
        switch(digita){
            case 1:
            valor += 180;
            System.out.println("Total: R$180,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
            case 2:
            valor += 200;
            System.out.println("Total: R$200,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
            case 3:
            valor += 240;
            System.out.println("Total: R$240,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
        }
        return valor;
    }
    public static int tamanhoPulseira(int digita){
        int tamanhopulseira = 0;
        switch(digita){
            case 1:
            tamanhopulseira = 17;
            break;
            case 2:
            tamanhopulseira = 18;
            break;
            case 3:
            tamanhopulseira = 20;
            break;
        }
        return tamanhopulseira;
    }
    public static int menuAcessorio(){
        System.out.println("1.Bichinhos (1,3cm) - R$225,00\n2.Bonequinhos (1,5cm) - R$185,00\n3.Berloques (0,5cm) - R$200,00\n4.Cubinhos (1cm) - R$190,00\n5.Rolinho (2cm) - Prata, Pedra e Esmaltados\n6.Ir para o pagamento");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int digita2 = in.nextInt();
        return digita2;
    }
    public static double suporte(double valor){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nDeseja adquirir um suporte de segurança pelo preço de R$95,00?\n1.Sim\n2.Não");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    if(digita == 1){
        valor += 95;
    }
    return valor;
   }
   public static int menuPagamento(){
       System.out.println("\nA loja oferece os seguintes tipos de pagamento:");
       System.out.println("\n1. À vista com 5% de desconto");
       System.out.println("\n2. 3 vezes no cartão sem acrescimos");
       System.out.println("\n3. 5 vezes no cartão com acresimo de 10% no preço total");
       System.out.println("\n4. 10 vezes no cartão com acresimo de 20% no preço total");
       System.out.println("\nDigite o número da forma de pagamento escolhida.");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int digita3 = in.nextInt();
       return digita3;
    }
   public static double pagamento(double valor, int digita3){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pagar = 0;
    double valor2 = 0;
    switch(digita3){
        case 1:
        valor = valor*0.95;
        break;
        case 2:
        pagar = valor/3;
        break;
        case 3:
        valor2 = (valor*110)/100;
        pagar = valor2/5;
        break;
        case 4:
        valor2 = (valor*120)/100;
        pagar = valor2/10;
        break;
    }
    //Condição para mostrar o valor total de acordo com o pagamento escolhido
    if (digita3 == 3){
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor2);
    } else if (digita3 == 4){
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor);
    }
    //Condição para mostrar o valor total e o valor das parcelas se a pessoa escolheu parcelado
    if(digita3 == 2){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 3 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    }  else if(digita3 == 3){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 5 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    }else if(digita3 == 4){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 10 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    int digita = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("\nObrigado por comprar conosco!");
    return valor;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int digita=Menu();
    double valor = valorPulseira(digita);
    int tamanhopulseira = tamanhoPulseira(digita);
    double tamanhototal = 0;
    int digita2;
    do {
            digita2=menuAcessorio();
            switch(digita2){
            case 1:
            valor += 225;
            tamanhototal += 1.3;
            break;
            case 2:
            valor += 185;
            tamanhototal += 1.5;
            break;
            case 3:
            valor += 200;
            tamanhototal += 0.5;
            break;
            case 4:
            valor += 190;
            tamanhototal += 1;
            break;
            case 5:
            tamanhototal += 2;
            System.out.println("Escolha o material:\n1.Prata - R$150,00\n2.Pedras - R$220,00\n3.Esmaltados - R$198,00");
            int rolinho = in.nextInt();
            switch(rolinho){
                case 1:
                valor += 150;
                break;
                case 2:
                valor += 220;
                break;
                case 3:
                valor += 198;
                break;
            }
            }
            if(tamanhototal > tamanhopulseira){
                System.out.println("\nTamanho máximo da pulseira atingido\n1.Prosseguir para o pagamento.");
                int digita3 = in.nextInt();
            }
            if(digita==6){
                System.out.println("\nDigite 1 para prosseguir para o pagamento.");
                int digita4 = in.nextInt();
            }
        } while (digita2 != 6 && tamanhototal < tamanhopulseira);
    valor += suporte(valor);
    System.out.println("\nO preço total da compra fica de: R$" +valor);
    int digita3 = menuPagamento();
    double pagamento = pagamento(valor, digita3);
}
}
```

Os valores estão na main e eu gostaria de separálos em uma função que eu possa chamar na main, como eu fiz com os outros.

Comment: coloque apenas a parte do código que é relevante ao problema

Comment: eu botei o código inteiro porque tem os outros métodos e eu achei que daria para entender melhor o objetivo do programa (que é a divisão em métodos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só pode alterar mais de uma variável por referência, e basicamente no Java não é possível passar parâmetros por referência.

Para fazer isso, você precisa de uma classe que possui a quantidade de valores que você quer retornar.

Por exemplo : Vamos supor que desejamos uma função que acresça 1 em dois números passados como parâmetro.

Não é possível fazer isso:

```
    public void teste() { 
      int a = 1; 
      int b = 2; 
      incrementa(a,b); 
    } 

    public void incrementa(int a ,int b) { 
      a = a + 1; 
      b = b + 1; 
    }
```

Nesse momento `a = 1` , e `b = 2` . Se esperávamos `a = 2`, `b = 3` , frustramo-nos. Em Java todos os parâmetros são passados por valor, exceto objetos, *[que são passados por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%C3%AAncia)*.

Para termos no escopo da função teste `a = 2` e `b = 3` após a chamada do método incrementa, devemos criar a seguinte classe:

```
        /** 
        * 
        * @Classe que possui dois inteiros como atributos 
        */ 
     public class valores{ 
        int x; 
        int y; 
        /** Construtor da Classe*/ 
      public valores(int numero1, numero2) 
        { 
          this.x = numero1; 
          this.y = numero2; // Estamos atribuindo valores às variáveis x e y desta classe. 
        } 

    }
```

E, voltando ao exemplo inicial, teríamos:

```
    public AlteraDoisValores incrementaValores(int a , int b) { 
              AlteraDoisValores alteraValores = new AlteraDoisValores(a,b); 
              alteraValores.x = alteraValores.x + 1 ; 
              alteraValores.y = alteraValores.y + 1 ; 
              return alteraValores; 
            } 
            //Esse método retorna um objeto do Tipo AlteraDoisValores, 
            //que contém seus atributos com os valores modificados. 

    public void teste() {
          int a = 1; 
          int b = 2; 
        AlteraDoisValores numeros; // Criamos uma variável do tipo numeros 
        numeros = incrementaValores(a,b); 
        // Dizemos que número aponta para a mesma 
        // *referência* do retorno da função alteraValores 
        a = numeros.x; 
        b = numeros.y; // Fazemos com que os nossos números primários sejam modificados 

        } // Agora temos a = 2 e b = 3
```

Deixando claro que, como dito no inicio do texto java não suporta retorno de múltiplos valores, então o que fizemos é considerado gambiarra, e de acordo com o projeto isso poderia não ser considerado uma boa prática.

O mais recomendado a fazer é que cada método, faça apenas uma sub-tarefa, retornando assim apenas uma variável.

[Fonte 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

[Fonte 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832472/how-to-return-2-values-from-a-java-function)