# Entendendo ponteiros

Tags: c++, ponteiro

Estou tentando aprender C++ pela internet, entendi mais ou menos o que são ponteiros mais não vejo uma utilidade, não sei nada de C++ só não quero passar por cima desse assunto, fiz um teste que eu acho que deveria funcionar, pra ver a velocidade dos ponteiros vs as variáveis normais.

[image: Usando pointers]
[image: Sem usar pointers]

Porque nos dois testes a velocidade é praticamente a mesma se um usa pointers e o outro não?

Comment: Você não está vendo a utilidade deles porque está acompanhando material ruim, então provavelmente está aprendendo várias coisas do jeito errado. Agora estou sem tempo mas a resposta que conseguiu até agora não ajudou muito. O que mais tem é informação errada ou ruim na internet. Tinha uma época que aqui não acontecia isso, mas mudou. Veja se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info Mais perguntas que podem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ponteiro Veja esta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101. Ponteiro é um conceito fundamental para linguagens como o C++.

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e incluir o código ao invés de imagens? É ruim demais visualizar o que está escrito acessando o site pelo celular.

Comment: Obrigado pelos links.E não preciso colocar mais o código porque o @bfavaretto disse que array sao pointers entao os codigos sao iguais, chamam uma função com pointer.

Comment: @mbegginer O que o fato de array serem ponteiros tem a ver com você poder postar o código ou não?

Comment: @VictorStafusa acho que ele quis dizer, que já descobriu o que queria.
Mas mbegginer o que o bfavaretto quis dizer, é que quando você passa uma array para o pointer, está passando um pointer para o primeiro elemento da mesma...O pointer apontaria para o primeiro elemento da array.

Comment: Sim obrigado. Eu pensei que assim a função teria que copiar a array inteira,tipo os "999999 1ns" e depois adicionar  1 a cópia e mostrar o resultado, kkkk mas pelo jeito não.E eu to usando linuxLive e não tenho mais o código foi só um teste besta.

Answer (score 1):

Não há diferença em questão de velocidade...
Ponteiros apontam para um valor armazenado na memória...Enquanto as variáveis são espaços pré-definidos na memória para valores.

A diferença é só em questão de utilidade. Se você não tem necessidade, não precisa usar ponteiros apenas variáveis.

Comment: Obrigado.
 Eu vi na internet que quando voce chama a função ela copia o argumento, entao no 2 exemplo ela nao deveria copiar toda a array e os numeros dela, deixando mais lento? Ou sera que é porque uma array tambem é um ponteiro?
 E tambem qual a utilidade dos ponteiros entao? Eu procurei na internet e vi que você pode chamar uma função com alguma variavel e mudar essa variavel direto na memória e nao mudar a cópia dela. Mais o que mais da pra fazer?

Comment: Bom, como eu disse ele aponta para um valor armazenado na memória.
Seria algo tipo lea do Assembly...
Você pode utiliza-lo para modificar valores diretamente da memória...Exemplo: Você pode modificar valores na memória de outro processo, necessitando apenas do endereço na memória....
Em Assembly tem 1001 utilidades, visto que é de baixo nível...Mas não vejo muita utilidade no C++ fora essa, rsrs.  
Mas enfim, se você precisar modificar valores na memória por algum motivo, os ponteiros são úteis.

Comment: @mbegginer Seu exemplo foi infeliz, quando você passa uma array na verdade você está passando um ponteiro pro primeiro elemento dela.

Comment: Obrigado agora que percebi isso kkkkk, fiz 2 códigos iguais.