# Função com parâmetro sem nome

Tags: c++, funções, parâmetros

Qual o motivo para declarar uma função com essa assinatura?

```
void funcao1(Pessoa&);
void funcao2(Pessoa&,void*);

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE UserCalibration_CalibrationComplete(xn::SkeletonCapability& /*capability*/, XnUserID nId, XnCalibrationStatus eStatus, void* /*pCookie*/)
{
    XnUInt32 epochTime = 0;
    xnOSGetEpochTime(&epochTime);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Você está falando do `void*`? Ou você está falando dos parâmetros só terem tipo?

Comment: o `void*` e `Pessoa&`

Comment: Mas o que você está vendo de errado neles?  É normal. Diga qual é sua dúvida

Comment: Isso, quero saber o motivo dos parâmetros terem apenas o tipo, o `void*` até entendo. Mas o `Pessoa&` não entendo

Comment: O motivo é porque a linguagem foi definida assim, e alguém precisa declarar dessa forma que a linguagem permite. Se você não tiver uma dúvida específica, fica complicado explicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está declarando duas funções, ambas retornam nada.

Ambas possuem um primeiro parâmetro que será uma [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) para um dado do tipo `Pessoa`. Isto só existe em C++, não em C. Não confundir com o `&` usado em variáveis que é um operador de referência, ou seja, ele pega o endereço de memória da variável. Apesar do símbolo ser o mesmo, as funcionalidades se assemelharem, são coisas bem distintas. Em C++ referências são preferíveis aos ponteiros, sempre que possível.

Não confundir o parâmetro `xn::SkeletonCapability&` com o [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) `&epochTime` na linha dentro da função exemplo, são coisas bem distintas. No contexto do parâmetro e na posição colocada indica que está declarando uma referência. No contexto do argumento está mandando o compilador pegar o endereço de memória da variável a ser usada como argumento e passar esse endereço para o ponteiro que a função `xnOSGetEpochTime` está esperando.

A segunda função também possui um segundo parâmetro cujo tipo não está definido. É um coringa.

Isto não é muito comum em C++, tem outras formas de resolver isto. Mas assim é uma forma de determinar que o parâmetro pode receber qualquer coisa. Esta forma é mais comum em C.

Isto é um ponteiro para `void`, de uma certa forma pode ser lido como um ponteiro para qualquer dado, de qualquer tipo. Ou seja é possível passar qualquer coisa para este parâmetro.

Note que isto é apenas a [declaração das funções e não sua definição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101). Na definição é necessário colocar, além do tipo do parâmetro, uma variável que receberá o dado.

No exemplo colocado em edição posterior mostra que dois parâmetros estão sendo inutilizados com comentários. Provavelmente eles não estão sendo usados dentro da função, o que geraria um *warning*. Provavelmente esta foi a forma que usaram para que a variável não fosse criada mas ainda manter as posições dos parâmetros.

- [Artigo da Wikipedia sobre as referências do C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).
- [Resposta do SO sobre a diferença entre ponteiro e referência no contexto do C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/221800).
- [Mais uma pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765999/221800).
- [Documentação Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/references-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019).

Comment: Ah cara, certo certo. Faz sentido. Foi só o & que me deixou confuso. E também fiquei confuso pelo fato do código que estou utilizando declara a função e implementa, mas da forma como ta ali em cima. acho que por isso que ficou confuso. Vou adicionar um trecho de código lá, só pra ficar mais claro.

Obrigado @bigdown

Comment: Acho que o último parágrafo que eu coloquei agora é sua real dúvida. Antes não dava para perceber.

Comment: sim, é exatamente isso.