# Programa não executa o fluxo esperado

Tags: c++, algoritmo

Depois do "Ola, meu nome eh Locao......" pra mim, na lógica, deveria continuar, e se o usuário escrevesse 'conversar' ele ia falar "Oh, então voce quer conversar?!". Mas nesse momento pára, simplesmente não aparece nada depois disso, ai se escrevo qualquer coisa ele vai para o último `if` e acaba.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



    //Variaveis
    char assunto[50] = "conversar";



    //Logica
    int main()
    {
    cout << "Ola, meu nome eh LOCAO, e estou aqui para te ajudar, o que voce deseja?" << endl ;
    cin >> assunto;
    if (assunto == "conversar")
        cout<<"Oh! Entao você quer conversar?! Sobre o que?"<< endl;

    if (cin >> assunto)
        cout << "Ah sim, isso eh muito legal" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Criei outro project, e agora menciona caminho nao especificado! Antes nao funcionava quando dava f5, agora nem isso vai ¬¬

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Já que você está usando C++, porque não usa o tipo `string` existente na biblioteca padrão da linguagem? Assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Ola, meu nome eh LOCAO, e estou aqui para te ajudar, o que voce deseja?" << endl ;
    string assunto = "conversar";
    cin >> assunto;
    if (assunto == "conversar") cout << "Oh! Entao você quer conversar?! Sobre o que?" << endl;
    if (cin >> assunto) cout << "Ah sim, isso eh muito legal" << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/zUT2ZK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kscixzfs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/StringComparing.cpp).

Aproveitei e organizei melhor o código.

Usando o tipo `string` você pode usar o operador de comparação. Do jeito que estava usando comparava duas [referências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) que obviamente são diferentes. Não comparava dois textos. Isto só ocorre com a sobrecarga do operador `==` no tipo `string`.

Talvez não esteja executando bem como você quer mas aí é um problema da lógica adotada e só você pode dizer sobre ela, pelo menos não há mais um erro de programação impedindo que o fluxo seja correto. Eu não usaria o `cin <<assunto` dentro da condição do `if`, nem sei qual o objetivo disto, provavelmente é uso equivocado.

Se insistir em usar um *array* de `char` aí a comparação tem que ser feita de com [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). A comparação direta estará comparando os ponteiros que apontam para o texto e não o texto em si.