# Como é a referência do C++?

Tags: c++, referência

```
class Data {

int d, m, a;
public: 

  void inic(int dd, int mm, int aa);
  void soma_ano(int n);
  void soma_mes(int n);
  void soma_dia(int n);

}; 


void timewarp(Data& d)
{
}
```

Pelo que entendi a variável `d` é de um tipo definido pelo programador, ou seja, uma classe. Mas o que significa este `&` em `Data&`?

Se trata de uma recursividade?

Estou quebrando a cabeça para entender essa passagem de parâmetro.

Comment: Tem algumas coisas esquisitas aí no código, mas vamos por partes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O parâmetro `d` do método `timeward` é uma referência para um objeto do tipo `Data` definido na aplicação.

Note que existe um membro chamado `d` dentro do tipo `Data`, que não pode ser confundido. Por isso nomes mais significativos seriam melhores.

Nada a ver com recursividade. É algo bem mais simples.

Pelo título você já tem uma noção do que seja. Neste caso você receberá uma [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) para o [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) passado para este método. Ou seja, o método receberá um ponteiro para o objeto, mas todo o acesso ao objeto será feito de forma natural, você não terá que tratar o ponteiro, o compilador tratará disto para você.

Quando o método for chamado o argumento passado será um valor do tipo `Data`. Algo assim:

```
timewarp(data);
```

Internamente o método fará algo assim:

```
d.soma_ano(1); //está somando 1 ano no dado
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/Reference.cpp).

Ao final da execução o argumento passado terá um ano a mais porque como foi passado por referência, qualquer alteração no parâmetro, refletirá no argumento, afinal ele está manipulando o mesmo objeto referenciado.

Se a declaração fosse simples, a passagem do parâmetro seria feita por cópia, ou seja, os dados do argumento seriam copiados no argumento. Além disto ser potencialmente mais lento (não muito neste caso específico), ao final da operação, haveria um descarte da informação, já que qualquer alteração seria feita na cópia do objeto e não no objeto original.

Comment: Agora entendi.  A variavel (Data& d) altera o pŕoprio objeto tipo Data e não uma cópia de como em (Data d).

Comment: Podemos dizer que uma referência é um ponteiro que nunca pode ser nulo (o compilador garante de forma mais positiva que uma referência é válida). De resto uma referência tem as mesmas vantagens do ponteiro (economizar uma cópia do objeto e polimorfismo - aceitar objetos de subclasses)

Comment: void timewarp(Data &d) em C++ seria o equivalente de passar o endereço de memoria de uma variavel na linguagem C ?

Comment: @Rogi93 Quase isso.