# Retorno múltiplo em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, return

É possível retornar vários valores? Por exemplo:

```
umafuncao()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    return x,y;
}

void main()
{
    int a, b;
    a, b = umafuncao();
}
```

Estou fazendo essa pergunta, pois construí um código utilizando essa estrutura para uma tarefa e passou em todos os testes, mas não encontro nada dizendo que isso é funcional.

Segue o código:

```
int findMaxCrossingSubArray(TItem *Receita, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int i, j, maxLeft, leftSum = -100000, maxRight, rightSum = -1000000;
    int sum = 0;
    for( i = mid; i >= low; i--)
    {
        sum = sum + Receita[i].Chave;
        if( sum > leftSum)
        {
            leftSum = sum;
            maxLeft = i;
        }
    }
    sum = 0;
    for(j = mid + 1; j <= high; j ++)
    {
        sum = sum + Receita[j].Chave;
        if(sum > rightSum)
        {
            rightSum = sum;
            maxRight = j;
        }
    }
return (maxLeft, maxRight, leftSum + rightSum);
}

int findMaxSubArray(TItem *Receita, int low, int high)
{
int mid;
int leftLow, leftHigh, leftSum;
int rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum;
int crossLow, crossHigh, crossSum;

if(high == low)
{
    return (low, high, Receita[low].Chave);
}
else
{
    mid = (low + high)/2;
    leftLow, leftHigh, leftSum = findMaxSubArray(Receita, low, mid);
    rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum = findMaxSubArray(Receita, mid+1, high);
    crossLow, crossHigh, crossSum = findMaxCrossingSubArray(Receita, low, mid, high);
    if((leftSum >= rightSum) && (leftSum >= crossSum))
        return (leftLow, leftHigh, leftSum);
    else if((rightSum >= leftSum) && (rightSum >= crossSum))
        return (rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum);
    else
        return (crossLow, crossHigh, crossSum);
    }
}

int main()
{
    TItem *Receita;
    int low = 0, ndias, *taxa, lucro;
    taxa = malloc(sizeof(int));

    ndias = Carrega(&Receita, taxa);

    //Aqui começa a lógica para calculo do lucro maximo:

    low, ndias, lucro = findMaxSubArray(Receita, low, ndias-1);
    printf("%d", lucro > 0 ? lucro : 0);
    Libera(&Receita);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Para returnar mais do que um valor, têm de retornar um array ou um pointer.

Comment: A primeira parte tem alguma relação com a segunda parte? Explique melhor porque a segunda parte é importante. Você está falando disto ` return (low, high, Receita[low].Chave)`?

Comment: Se você criar um struct (tipo de dados composto) você pode usar ele para empacotar vários valores no retorno da função.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10):

## Retorno múltiplo

Nem C nem C++ permitem retornar vários valores na função.

O mais comum quando é necessário retornar mais de um valor seria passar um [parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) por [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101), assim você coloca um valor nele dentro da função e quando sair dela esse valor ficará na variável passada. Isto costuma ser usado quando os valores retornados tem pouca relação ou está usando técnicas mais antigas.

Outra possibilidade mais moderna é usar uma estrutura de dados que encapsule todos os valores. Pode ser algum tipo de coleção, como o *array* padrão do C, o `Vector` que obviamente só funcionam se o tipo for o mesmo, mas eles não dão boa semântica ao código. Pode ser uma `struct` ou `class`, ou uma [`Tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), o mais comum nesses casos.

A tupla é vantajosa quando os dados são relacionados e heterogêneos, como em uma classe. Retornar uma classe é usada quando estes dados tem uma semântica maior na aplicação e provavelmente é usada em outros locais. Não vale a pena criar uma classe apenas para este retorno múltiplo único.

## Operador de vírgula

Mas o que você viu no código apresentado não é um múltiplo retorno. O operador representado pela vírgula é o [operador de sequência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Ele executará todas as expressões separadas por cada vírgula, em ordem e a última expressão será responsável pelo resultado de toda a sequência. Então em:

```
return (maxLeft, maxRight, leftSum + rightSum);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/Comma.cpp).

o retorno será o valor de `leftSum + rightSum`. Não me pergunte porque tem os valores anteriores. Eles serão descartados e não possuem função alguma ali. Neste caso, não faz sentido porque elas não executam nada, só pegam o valor que serão posteriormente descartados.

Answer (score 7):

O que você está usando sem perceber é o obscuro **Operador Vírgula**.
Esse operador avalia a expressão à esquerda, descarta seu valor, avalia o da direita e retorna seu valor.
Por exemplo: `1, 2` tem o valor 2. Então, `int x = 1, 2;` é equivalente a `int x = 2;` . Isso parece sem sentido, mas, se você tiver uma expressão do tipo `int x = a(), b();` e a função a tiver efeitos colaterais (modificar o estado do programa), vai ser diferente de `int x = b();`

No caso de usar o operador vírgula como *lvalue* (lado esquerdo de uma atribuição), como em     `a, b = umafuncao();`o compilador só está permitindo porque você está usando C++, que permite isso (portanto, sua tag C é inadequada a essa pergunta).

Agora quanto à sua solução, eu não te recomendo usar um vetor para retornar seus valores, como foi sugerido, pois seus valores, apesar de terem o mesmo tipo de dado, possuem **semânticas** diferentes. Isso é relevante porque quem receber o seu retorno vai ter que olhar o seu código pra descobrir o que significa cada posição do seu vetor. O mais adequado é criar uma classe simples que mantém os valores que você quer retornar dando a eles os devidos nomes (leftLow, leftHigh etc.). Ao contrário do que pode parecer, não, uma classe dessas não é pesada pois é bastante otimizável-- é salva praticamente como uma sequência dos bits dos seus membros.

Comment: +1 pela explicação do operador virgula. 
Dois comentários apenas: 
int x = 1, 2; não é uma expressão válida. Esta expressão deverá retornar algo do género "expected unqualified-id before numeric constant"
Já, int a = 1; int b = 2; int x = a, b; é válido mas no no final x será igual a 1;

Comment: Tem razão. Faltaram os parêntesis. Vou consertar. :)

Answer (score 4):

Olá você pode fazer o uso de vetores para isso.

> Exemplo

```
int * umafuncao()
{
    static int retorno[2];
    retorno[0] = 1;
    retorno[1] = 2;

    return retorno;
}

void main()
{
    int *callfunc;
    int a, b;
    callfunc = umafuncao();
    a = callfunc[0];
    b = callfunc[1];
}
```

> Ou fazer o uso de ponteiros...

```
void umafuncao(int *a, int *b)
{
    //Altero o valor direto na posição da memoria da variavel.
    *a = 1;
    *b = 2;
}

void main()
{
    int a, b;
    umafuncao(&a, &b);
}
```

Comment: Acho meio frágil usar memória estática pra retornar valores como no primeiro exemplo. Acho que seria mais normal simplesmente retornar um struct.

Comment: Sim Hugo, não sou muito expert em C manjo mais de PHP/JAVA.. Apenas sugeri como eu faria, não sei se é a maneira correta. Só queria ajudar..

Answer (score 2):

O C++17 nos introduziu ao maravilhoso mundo das [Ligações Estruturadas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) (Structured Bindings).

Essa nova feature permite que você retorne uma tupla (Ou um objeto que se comporte como uma), e utilizar um pequeno açúcar sintáctico para preencher múltiplas váriáveis com os itens deste objeto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

auto f() {
    return std::make_tuple(1, 2);
}

int main() {
    auto [a, b] = f(); // Aqui
    std::cout << '(' << a << ',' << b << ')';
}
```

### [Ver no coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fba35ad4567cbf8a)

Esse trecho de código é equivalente ao seguinte trecho, compilável em C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int> f() {
    return std::make_tuple(1, 2);
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::tie(a, b) = f();
    std::cout << '(' << a << ',' << b << ')';
}
```

### [Ver no coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d129dc9a0b0208f7)