# Quais as diferenças entre ponteiro e referência em c++?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, referência

Essa pergunta é uma versão específica para c++ da pergunta: [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%C3%AAncia)

Na prática, quais as diferenças entre um ponteiro e uma referência em C++?

Digo na prática porque não gostaria de respostas meramente descritivas e às vezes ambíguas, como [algumas nessa pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in). O que busco são ilustrações práticas dessas diferenças, que além da explicação contenham exemplos de códigos simples e diretos ao ponto.

Answer (score 3):

- referencias em sí (não o tipo referenciado), são sempre `const`, portanto inicializadas sempre uma única vez, ponteiros não.

Pode ser difícil imaginar uma tentativa de reinicialização de uma referência, já que depois da inicialização inicial onde se faz o *bind* com uma variável,
as atribuíções seguintes vão sempre tratar a referência como um alias para a variável original, e não uma tentativa de fazer *rebind* à uma outra variável.
Mas é possível replicar isto quando se lida com referências de forma indireta, forçando a situação de *rebind*, exemplo:

```
struct S {
    int &x;
};

int main() {
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    S s1{ a }, s2 { b };

    s2 = s1;

    // Clang Error:
    //
    // refs.cpp:9:8: error: object of type 'S' cannot be assigned because its
    //                      copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
    //     s2 = s1;
    //        ^
    // refs.cpp:2:10: note: copy assignment operator of 'S' is implicitly
    //                      deleted because field 'x' is of reference type
    //                      'int &'
    //     int &x;
    //          ^
    // 1 error generated.
}
```

`s1` e `s2` são dois objetos simples do tipo `S` que possuí um membro referência. Eu construo eles fazendo os membros referenciarem duas variáveis diferentes.

Quando tento fazer uma [atribuição trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator), que é apenas uma mera cópia de memória (o que em tese seria um meio de burlar o sistema pra conseguir vazer um *rebind* da referência interna, deixando as duas referenciando uma mesma variável, já que `s1` e `s2` seriam iguais bit-a-bit) o compilador não permite.

Este mesmo tipo de erro ocorreria caso o membro fosse um `const int x` ou `int * const x`, pois não é possível reinicializar variáveis `const`.

- referencias [nem sequer precisam ter representação em memória em tempo de execução](http://www.preney.ca/paul/archives/1051), ponteiros sim.
- membros referência tornam o [tipo não-regular](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=314) obrigatoriamente.
- não existe array de referências.
- não existe referência pra referência, [referências colapsam](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html), algo que não existe para ponteiros.
- Estilos diferentes de referência (lvalue reference vs rvalue reference) para [categorias de valor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) diferentes.

#### Bonus

C++ possui ponteiros e referências, Java, como muita gente diz, "passa objetos por referência". Na verdade não, na verdade Java tem ponteiros, e passa tudo por valor, incluindo os ponteiros, [erroneamente tratados de referência](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Comment: Ainda não entendo o que você quis dizer com o primeiro ponto. É como se não existisse `int& var = var2; var = 1;`

Comment: @LucasHenrique isto que você fez é uma mudança no valor referenciado, não um rebind da referência pra outra variável.

Comment: @LucasHenrique ponteiros podem ser `int *var` ou `const int *var` ou `int * const var` ou `const int * const var`. Uma coisa é o tipo apontado ser constante, outra a variável em sí.

Comment: Ah. Isso realmente está certo. Só está meio ambíguo. Acho que seria melhor se você colocasse "referencias em sí, ou seja, o bloco de memória para qual ela aponta [...]"

Comment: @LucasHenrique é justamente "o bloco de memória para qual ela aponta" que pode ou não ser const, ela em sí não, é sempre const. Ficaria errado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34258/discussion-between-lucas-henrique-and-pepper-chico).

Comment: Pepper, não seria possível colocar exemplos de código para cada um dos pontos?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Sim, só não tenho tempo agora. Fica pra mais tarde.

Comment: Java não usou o termo referência antes de C++?

Comment: @Pablo creio que não, c++ existe antes da existência do java, e "referência" de fato dá nome a um elemento da sintaxe do c++, diferente do uso que se tem deste termo em java por exemplo. Não obstante, vale ler o artigo que passei a respeito, que prova que java na verdade têm uma espécie de ponteiro restrito, estes que são normalmente tratados como "referência" de certa forma errônea.

Answer (score 1):

Referências fazem papel semelhante a um ponteiro, porém o endereço a que ela referencia é imutável. Quando você mexe em uma referência, não está fazendo nada além de mexer na variável a qual ela se referencia, isso nunca muda. São equivalentes, porém devem ser utilizados conforme os casos em que são pedidos, desempenhando suas funções fundamentais. Também há um tipo específico de referências que se comportam de maneira diferente, chamada de [referência rvalue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd293668.aspx). Ela é usada quando o [tempo de vida da variável é pequeno](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/f90831hc.aspx).

---

O que também muda é a maneira de como o compilador vai tratar a variável que você tem, o syntactic sugar e boas práticas. Isso é muito geral, dessa maneira, então analisemos um exemplo. Se você tem uma função `int f(int&)`, você pode entrar tanto com um `int&` ou com um `*(int*)`, correto -  nesses casos, eles necessariamente se complementam. Porque isso é o básico, um conceito que surgiu do C para o C++. Se você for olhar as APIs mais comuns do Windows ou do Linux, você vai perceber que variáveis que mudam sempre são passadas por ponteiros, já que **em C não existiam referências**. Eles criaram essas referências para tornar o programa mais seguro e "bonito" pois, afinal, ponteiros são uma das coisas mais "imprevisíveis" quanto a erros de programação.

Se conheces Assembly, a diferença de um ponteiro é que, (analogamente, não literalmente,) quanto você chama um mnemônico ou realiza uma função, ele realiza `MNM var`, e com uma referência, `MNM [var]`. Isso equivale a dizer que o C++ trata, na maior parte das vezes, referências como ponteiros dereferenciados, ponteiros como referências de uma variável, e vice versa. Eles são semelhantes, mas diferentes na prática, como o exemplo da função. Na prática, quando você tiver uma cadeia de dados na memória, peça um ponteiro. Se você precisar de uma variável para *alterar na memória*, peça uma referência. Quanto mais limpo um código for, menos chances de errar vão existir.

---

Exemplo:

```
void f(int&&);
int main()
{
    int var;
    int& referencia = var;
    referencia = 1; // o valor de var agora é 1
    std::cout << (int)&referencia; //imprime o endereço em que var se encontra, dando o ponteiro para a variável
    &referencia = (int*)0; // ERRO: imutável
    f(1); //imprime 1, valor literal
    f(referencia); // ERRO
}

void f(int&& var)
{
    std::cout << var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma referência é "segura": não pode ser nula e o compilador garante que ela aponta para um objeto válido. Você não pode simplesmente declarar uma variável

```
Objeto &x;
```

porque então a variável seria nula ou inválida. A declaração precisa incluir a definição:

```
Objeto y = Objeto();
Objeto &x = y;          // x e y são o mesmo objeto
```

Numa classe, você pode declarar um membro que é uma referência, mas tem de usar a sintaxe "lista de inicialização de membro", para garantir que o membro já seja válido quando o corpo do construtor começar a rodar:

```
class Bla {
   Objeto &x;
   Bla(Objeto &param): x(param) {
       ... 
   }
};
```

Note que para poder iniciar o membro x, uma referência a Objeto teve de ser enviada como parâmetro ao construtor, porque uma referência válida tem de ir de algum lugar, ela não se materializa do nada.

Referências a objetos, assim como ponteiros a objetos, permitem o uso de polimorfismo. Se OutroObjeto for uma subclasse de Objeto, a seguinte sintaxe é válida:

```
OutroObjeto y = OutroObjeto();
Objeto &x = y;
```

Ponteiros podem ser nulos (o que às vezes é uma vantagem), podem apontar para objetos que já foram liberados da memória, e podem até apontar para posições arbitrárias de memória, mediante casts inseguros.

Se não houver um motivo específico para usar ponteiros e/ou objetos alocados com new, é sempre melhor usar referências a objetos criados em pilha.