# Alteração de tamanho do vetor em uma estrutura

Tags: c, c++, array, struct

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
struct Implicantes{
    int posicao;
    char binario[5];
    bool dontcare;
    bool tick;
    struct Implicantes *Next;
};
```

É possível alterar o tamanho do vetor de `char` "binario" de 5 para o tamanho de uma variável que viria como parâmetro de entrada para a estrutura (não sei se isso é possível também)? Preciso que o tamanho do vetor da estrutura mude durante o código mas não sei como fazer essa alteração.

Comment: Essa mudança (configuração das instancias da estrurura) precisa acontecer em tempo de compilação ou em tempo de execução? Todas as variáveis da estrutura terão sempre o mesmo tamanho do vetor ?

Comment: O seu programa é em C ou em C++. São linguagens diferentes e, portanto, soluções diferentes. Por exemplo, `bool` é algo que não existe em C

Comment: Quando vejo essas estruturas com um ponteiro chamado `Next`, já imagino que é trabalho pra faculdade/escola e listas encadeadas..., mas quando vejo o nome `Implicantes` imagino que alguém esteja fazendo um jogo hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou cobrir uma solução em C++ para o seu problema:

> É possível alterar o tamanho do vetor de `char` "binario" (...)

Não é possível alterar o tamanho de uma array durante a execução do programa (usei o termo array ao invés de vetor e já deixarei claro a razão disso). Você terá de usar de outro tipo de variável, como nos exemplos das outras respostas. Em C++, existe uma solução padrão para quando queremos um número variável de elementos do mesmo tipo (no seu caso, um número variável de `char`), e é uma classe chamada `vector`:

```
#include <vector>

struct Implicantes{
  int posicao;
  bool dontcare;
  bool tick;
  struct Implicantes *Next;
  std::vector<char> binario;
};
```

Agora sim: um vetor, de tamanho variável, de `char`. Se esse código lhe parece estranho, vou esmiuçar um pouco, mas acho que uma explicação completa sai do escopo da pergunta:

O `std::` indica que estamos usando um elemento da biblioteca padrão do C++ (std é uma abreviação de standard), estes elementos ficam todos dentro de um `namespace` com esse nome. E o `<char>` indica que tipo de variável o vetor guarda, você pode criar um `vector<int>`, `vector<bool>`, `vector<Implicantes>`, `vector<qualquer_classe>`.

No seu exemplo, a variável `binario` tem tamanho cinco, fixo, e espaço reservado para os cinco `chars`(que é a razão pela qual seu tamanho não pode ser alterado), já o vetor pode ter qualquer tamanho, e por isso ainda não possui espaço reservado. O que leva a segunda parte da questão...

> (...) de 5 para o tamanho de uma variável que viria como parâmetro de entrada para a estrutura (não sei se isso é possível também)

Imagino que você seja novo a linguagem e não conheça construtores. Construtores são exatamente funções que recebem parâmetros no momento da criação de um objeto. Por exemplo:

```
struct Implicantes{
  int posicao;
  bool dontcare;
  bool tick;
  struct Implicantes *Next;
  std::vector<char> binario;
  //construtor recebe parâmetro e define tamanho do vetor [binario]
  Implicantes(unsigned int quantos_binario)
  {
    //resize é um método que altera o número de elementos do vetor
    binario.resize(quantos_binario);
  }
};
```

Essa função com o mesmo nome da estrutura é um construtor, e agora para criar um `Implicantes` você vai ter de fornecer um número, como no exemplo:

```
int main() {
  //cria Implicantes com binario contendo 2 char
  Implicantes A(2);
  //cria Implicantes com binario contendo 7 char
  Implicantes B(7);
}
```

Se você ainda quer poder criar um `Implicantes` sem dizer quantos elementos `binario` deve ter, pode declarar um construtor sem parâmetros, e este será usado quando você não fornecer nenhum parâmetro:

```
struct Implicantes{
    int posicao;
    bool dontcare;
    bool tick;
    struct Implicantes *Next;
    std::vector<char> binario;
    //construtor recebe parâmetro e define tamanho do vetor [binario]
    Implicantes(unsigned int quantos_binario)
    {
        binario.resize(quantos_binario);
    }
    //construtor sem nenhum parâmetro, define tamanho de vetor [binario] para 5
    Implicantes()
    {
        binario.resize(5);
    }
};
```

E agora...

```
int main() {
  //cria Implicantes com binario contendo 2 char
  Implicantes A(2);
  //cria Implicantes com binario contendo 7 char
  Implicantes B(7);
  //cria Implicantes com binario contendo 5 char
  //através do construtor padrão
  Implicantes C;
}
```

Depois que você definiu o tamanho do vetor, é só usar normalmente como com as arrays:

```
int main() {
  Implicantes C;
  C.binario[0] = '0';
  C.binario[1] = '1';
  C.binario[2] = 'z';
  //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Se fosse um vetor em C++ poderia. Um *array* em C, como foi usado, não pode. Se estiver usando C++, ou muda para [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (no caso de `char` pode usar [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)) ou em C ou C++ muda para [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) e arca com todas consequências disto, como cuidar da alocação (tem exemplo na resposta do Anthony Accioly, mas note que terá que cuidar disto sempre), talvez não seja o que deseja.

Em qualquer caso se tiver que limitar o tamanho terá que ser feito manualmente. Em C é possível criar algumas facilidades, mas o consumidor dessa estrutura terá que lidar com tudo por vontade própria. Em C++ é possível abstrair todo o controle de acesso, mas dá um pouco mais de trabalho.

Até é possível ter um *array* único no final de um estrutura sem tamanho definido em C, mas não é compatível com todos compiladores, poucas pessoas usam, não é tão recomendado e acaba funcionando como um ponteiro. Melhor nem tentar.

Answer (score 4):

No [c](/questions/tagged/c) você geralmente resolve isso com um ponteiro do tipo `char` e `malloc` para reservar o espaço dinamicamente:

```
struct Implicantes {
    int posicao;
    char *binario;
    bool dontcare;
    bool tick;
    struct Implicantes *Next;
}; 

struct Implicantes imp;
imp.binario = malloc(50 * sizeof *imp.binario);  
// 50 pode ser substituido por qualquer tamanho  

// ou ainda, se tudo vai ficar em escopo comum
// char s[50];
// imp.binario = s;
```

No [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) eu simplesmente usaria uma [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

```
struct Implicantes {
    int posicao;
    std::string binario;
    bool dontcare;
    bool tick;
    struct Implicantes *Next;
}; 

struct Implicantes imp = {};
std::string binario = "Essa e uma string chamada binario";
```