# Por que em métodos set no C++ eu tenho que usar o parâmetro como referência?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Eu peguei essa classe `Pessoa` como exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa{
private: 
     string nome;

public:
     string getNome();
     void setNome(const string &nome);
};
```

A minha dúvida é: por que eu devo utilizar um parâmetro por referência no método `void setNome(const string &nome);`?

Comment: Se não estou enganado, `public class Pessoa`não é C++ válido...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo mesmo motivo que tem que usar em qualquer outro tipo de método. Ou não deve usar em qualquer método. Vamos entender.

Dados são passados para o parâmetro por valor, então o valor do argumento é copiado para a variável que representa o parâmetro. Sempre.

O que pode fazer é obrigar que um parâmetro receba um ponteiro, provavelmente criando uma referência para o valor que se deseja manipular dentro do método. Uma das formas de fazer isso é determinando que o parâmetro seja uma referência, através do `&`. Assim a referência é o valor.

Nada impede de criar o método sem a referência, mas copiar todo o dado para dentro do método pode ser muito custoso. Isso vale para qualquer método sem distinção.

Nesse caso pode ser interessante usar a referência já que uma *string* é passada por valor e é muito grande, podendo gerar um alto custo na passagem do dado.

Alguns compiladores fazem otimizações para `string` e evitam o custo da cópia de toda estrutura. Mas não pode contar com isso se a performance for importante em qualquer cenário. Em versões novas C++ usa uma referência com semântica de *move* explícita e garante a otimização.

Agora eu devolvo a pergunta, por que acha que tem que fazer isso sempre? Se leu em algum lugar, ensinaram errado ou não entendeu o contexto.

Leituras adicionais recomendáveis:

- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) (é outra linguagem mas a base é ma mesma)
- [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)

Comment: Bem, eu estou estudando Orientação a Objetos com C++, como você pode perceber, já que usei essa linguagem como exemplo. Eu acho ela bem mais intuitiva de entender os conceitos de OO, já que falhei com outras.

Comment: Mas respondendo a sua pergunta, eu vi um exemplo usando um inteiro e achei que com string também seria do mesmo modo. Sempre tive essa dúvida em saber se devo usar referência ou não.

Comment: Então o método void setNome(const string &nome); ficaria void setNome(string nome); ?

Comment: Um `int` é um tipo naturalmente por valor e pequeno, não vejo motivo para usar uma referência nesse caso. Ou seja, a pergunta parte de uma premissa errada. Talvez ela deveria ter mostrado o que viu, o que pretende e tentar entender dentro do contato apresentado. Um exemplo solto assim não ajuda muito nesse caso. Nesse exemplo eu não usaria a referência. Se fosse um `int` provavelmente não usaria, mas depende do contexto. No exemplo por sem uma `string` tem chance da referência dar uma performance melhor em alguns casos.

Comment: Muito obrigado por tudo!