# Ler e imprimir valores de uma struct

Tags: c, c++, struct

Tenho um algoritmo que leia nome, setor e número de 10 funcionários, estou tentando ler em uma função porém não estou conseguindo, quando tento imprimir só saem números. Esse é um conteúdo que não entendi nem um pouco, então pode ser que tenham erros descarados.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
string nome;
string setor;
int cartao;
}funcionario;


void inserir(funcionario func)
{
cin >> func.nome;
cin >> func.setor;
cin >> func.cartao; 
}

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
funcionario func[10];
int opcao=0, p=0;

do{
    cout << "O que você deseja fazer?\nDigite \"1\" para inserir.\nDigite\"2\" para buscar.\n";
    cin >> opcao;

    if(opcao != 1 && opcao != 2){
        cout << "Valor digitado inválido, digite novamente.\n";
    }
    else if(opcao == 1){
        inserir(func[p]);
        p++;
    }

  }while(p < 10);
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Em nenhum momento este código tenta imprimir algo. O principal problema dele é que não está [passando o elemento por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81611/101), então quando termina de executar a função de inserir o dado é perdido. Sugiro fortemente [estudar o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149513/101) antes de continuar, porque dei a solução, mas sem entender todo o funcionamento do modelo de memória do C++ estará só resolvendo o problema sem saber como aplicar novamente. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320739/101).

Melhorei mais algumas coisas, principalmente porque está programando em C++ e não em C, mas não melhorei tudo, também recomendo ver a forma idiomática para [fazer o código em C++ e não usar C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/392951/101).

A lógica também pode ser melhorada.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Funcionario {
    string nome;
    string setor;
    int cartao;
};

void inserir(Funcionario& func) {
    cin >> func.nome;
    cin >> func.setor;
    cin >> func.cartao; 
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    Funcionario funcionarios[10];
    int p = 0;
    do {
        cout << "O que você deseja fazer?\nDigite \"1\" para inserir.\nDigite\"2\" para buscar.\n";
        int opcao = 0;
        cin >> opcao;
        if (opcao != 1 && opcao != 2) cout << "Valor digitado inválido, digite novamente.\n";
        else if (opcao == 1) {
            inserir(funcionarios[p]);
            p++;
        }
    } while (p < 10);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aGMI11). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InsertData). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/InsertData.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Na declaração da função "inserir" o parâmetro "funcionario" precisa ser declarado "por referência", com um "&" ao lado do tipo do funcionário:

```
void inserir(funcionario& func) // <--------- parametro por referencia
{
  cin >> func.nome;
  cin >> func.setor;
  cin >> func.cartao; 
}
```

Desta maneira a função trabalha com o objeto "func" original. Sem o "&" a função recebe (atenção aqui) uma cópia do objeto original, entao tudo que for alterado no objeto dentro da função se perde quando a função retorna, pois o objeto cópia usado pela função é destruído no retorno da função.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar uma função de cadastro que seja capaz de registrar uma quantidade `n` de funcionários, veja só:

```
void inserir( funcionario * func, int qtd )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < qtd; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Cadastro do funcionario (id=" << i+1 << "):" << endl;
        cout << "  Nome: ";
        cin >> func[i].nome;
        cout << "  Setor: ";
        cin >> func[i].setor;
        cout << "  Cartao: ";
        cin >> func[i].cartao;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Juntando tudo conforme o seu raciocínio, teremos algo como:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    string nome;
    string setor;
    int cartao;
} funcionario;


void inserir( funcionario * func, int qtd )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < qtd; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Cadastro do funcionario (id=" << i+1 << "):" << endl;
        cout << "  Nome: ";
        cin >> func[i].nome;
        cout << "  Setor: ";
        cin >> func[i].setor;
        cout << "  Cartao: ";
        cin >> func[i].cartao;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    funcionario func[10];
    int opcao=0;

    while(1) {
        cout << "Selecione uma opcao:" << endl;
        cout << "1) Inserir." << endl;
        cout << "2) Buscar." << endl;
        cout << "> ";
        cin >> opcao;

        if(opcao == 1){
            inserir( func, 10 );
        }
        else if(opcao == 2){
        }
        else {
            cout << "Valor digitado inválido, digite novamente.\n";
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```