# Operador & no C++

Tags: c++, ponteiro

Estou estudando C++ e tenho dúvida com relação a esse operador &, quando devo usar?

```
void funct(int *var) {

    (*var)++;
}

void funct(int& var) {

    var++;
}
```

Essas duas função incrementa a varial, mas eu não sei dizer a diferença.

Comment: Acho que isto responde http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101

Comment: No exemplo não funciona no C, por que?

Comment: Porque o C não tem referências só ponteiros.