# Padrão da linguagem C++ para ponteiro

Tags: c++, ponteiro, estilo-de-codificação

Estou começando os estudos em C++ gostaria qual é a recomendação da linguagem (padrão de mercado) para se referenciar um ponteiro.

ex:

```
l->propriedade;
```

ou

```
(*l).propriedade;
```

Acredito que não exista diferença de performance e código, apenas maneiras diferentes de fazer a mesma coisa, existe alguma recomendação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira é a mais adequada com certeza. Na verdade em essência ninguém faz a segunda a não ser para demonstrar que é possível (e que é um *syntax sugar*) ou se tiver algum caso muito específico (estou especulando, não me lembro de algum caso onde isso seja necessário.)

A segunda opção definitivamente não é mais parecida com C#, pelo contrário, ela é bem menos parecida com C#. Ela usa um ponteiro e C# não tem ponteiro (em quase todos os casos, todos que quase todos programadores usam), então não faz sentido fazer essa comparação. Está comparando um detalhe bobo de sintaxe ser uma seta ou ponto (uma parte da sintaxe, e o resto é completamente *alien* em C#, exceto em código `unsafe`, memsmo neste caso ainda usaria a seta), com um detalhe importante de semântica que é usar um ponteiro de forma explícita ou não. Semântica importa, sintaxe não.

C é igual ao C++ nesse ponto.

O que existe só em C++ é a referência, esta sim fica mais parecida com o que é C#, porque usa o ponto para referenciar algo e não para acessar um ponteiro. Então se um objeto for acessado por uma referência pode usar semântica e sintaxe idêntica ao C# (sem contar certos detalhes que só fazem sentido em uma linguagem ou outra), afinal em C# tudo é [referência e não ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

Seria algo assim:

```
void Metodo(Tipo &objeto) {
    objeto.membro;
}
```

Se fosse ponteiro acessaria assim:

```
void Metodo(Tipo *objeto) {
    objeto->membro;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/Syntax.cpp).

Não existe diferença de performance em qualquer caso relatado acima.

A pergunta tinha mais informações, então algumas coisas podem parecer esquisitas, eu respondi de acordo com a [versão original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/402090/1).

Comment: Desculpe mas não acho 'detalhe bobo' quero dizer que quando usa uma classe em C# e utiliza obj.propriedade e não obj->propriedade, por isso 'eu achei' essa caracteristica.
A pergunta não é se é um ponteiro ou não (claro que é) é se existe alguma recomendação para a linguagem, vou edita-la pra deixar mais clara a pergunta, creio que não soube me expressar direito.

Comment: Sim, você pode achar o que quiser, mas ainda é um detalhe bobo, por qualquer critério que use, é só dizer que um ponto é mais bonito que uma vírgula, é mais bobo do que discutir se deve usar espaço ou *tab*, se chaves são melhores que `begin` e ` end`, cada um tem sua preferência, mas muda nada no que está fazendo, é *bike sheding*. Eu á respondi sua pergunta (está na primeira linha), você só se ateve a outro detalhe bobo. em vez de se ater ao que interessa na resposta, não tenho porque mudar uma vírgula na minha resposta por causa da edição. Posso até melhorar o texto, mas o conteúdo é isso.

Comment: ok, relaxe..no stress

Comment: Eu tenho como te contestar porque não argumentou nada, se ler a frase que diz que não acha um detalhe bobo, só está dizendo, você acha isso, não tem argumento. Então se acha que é melhor usar da segunda forma, pode usar, é horrível, menos legível, ninguém faz isso, nada tem a ver com C#, nada, exceto que ele tem um ponto entre outras coisas, portanto é como dizer que as pessoas são parecidas porque o branco dos olhos é o mesmo.

Comment: ok..era só dizer, esse não é o padrão da comunidade c++, e não, isso é um 'detalhe bobo','é horrível', acho que o tom da resposta não é muito o que a comunidade preza(ok vc é moderador e sabe mais do q eu a respeito), acho que está cansado de responder 'perguntas dummy' e ai fica com mal humor..relaxe.

Comment: Novamente, está dito na primeira linha, você que está se apegando a um detalhe bobo da resposta. Se você acha bonito pode usar, mas qualquer outra pessoa dirá que é horrível fazer aquilo, por isso que em quase 50 anos atrás alguém criou um *sintaxe sugar* para evitar o uso de algo horrível, se não fosse não teriam criado isso.  Estou dando uma resposta tão objetiva quanto a pergunta pede, ela pede para falar sobre estilo de codificação, isso envolve alguma subjetividade, e eu estou lhe dando vários argumentos porque essa escolha foi feita (não por mim, mas por todo mundo).

Comment: O mal humor parece ser só seu, eu estou muito bem humorado, acho bem engraçada essas escolhas. Se você começar ler os textos sem deixar o seu mal humor interpretar será melhor. Você viu algo ruim em eu falar em detalhe bobo, eu só vi algo bom, é uma informação relevante, e te dei argumentos porque isso é bobo e não deve se preocupar com isso, ainda mais da forma como está se preocupando. Você acha a pergunta *dummy*, eu não acho, são as que mais gosto de responder porque mostra um caminho adequado dentro da minha experiência.

Comment: A sintaxe da referência está incorreta, deveria ser `void Metodo(Tipo &objeto)` (note o `&` antes do identificador).

Comment: E um motivo para se usar `(*a).b` sobre `a->b` em C++ é quando deseja-se não utilizar a sobrecarga do `operator->` de `a` (caso haja um).

Comment: E não entendi a razão para trazer C# na discussão, o autor da pergunta não questionou a comparação entre linguagens. Soa como um *red herring*.

Comment: É, eu inverti, obrigado. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/402090/1