# Por que listas (arrays) tem um comportamento diferentes das variáveis comuns em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Dois exemplos que eu acho que define bem minha questão, o primeiro é o de função:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def soma(l_item):
  l_item[0] += 10

soma(a)
print(a)

>>> [11, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Ela é alterada por funções.

O segundo é o de cópia:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.remove(1)

b = a

print(b)

>>> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

De fato eu sei copiar uma lista, e até já ouvi um pouco sobre o endereçamento na memória, mas infelizmente eu não consigo compreender bem o motivo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, o título fala algo equivocado.

> listas (arrays) tem um comportamento diferentes das variáveis comuns

Lista é um tipo de dado e [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um nome que define uma posição de memória, então comparar as duas coisas não faz sentido. Um dos motivos que eu vejo que as pessoas tem dificuldade de programar corretamente hoje em dia, e quase todo mundo que entra na área tem tido muita dificuldade, é que não entende bem o que são as coisas. Não tem como fazer certo sem entender profundamente, tem como fazer funcionar, que é diferente de estar certo. Em programação a única coisa fácil é fazer algo errado e ainda assim funcionar e a pessoa achar que está certo.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

O resto da pergunta parece ignorar o título. Parece que quer saber a diferença de uma lista e um tipo de dado escalar, ou seja, não composto. Ou melhor ainda e que não saberia definir neste momento, a diferença para um [tipo de dado por valor ou por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Se não entender [o que é uma referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101), tem pergunta feita.

## Tipo por valor e por referência

Pelo menos estamos falando de semântica, até porque Python usa tudo por referência, quando falamos em ser por referência é uma nova [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e tem caso que mantêm uma semântica de valor, como é `string`.

Então listas, dicionários e objetos definidos pelo programador são considerados como semântica por referência, em geral porque são grandes e mutáveis, portanto você quer que um transporte do objeto seja barato, e por ser grande quase sempre custará caro ele usa a indireção para apenas copiar o endereço de onde está o objeto e mantém um objeto único sem copiá-lo de verdade. Além deste ganho se você mexer no objeto em uma variável está sempre mexendo no mesmo objeto, o que em objetos mutáveis isso é desejável na esmagadora maioria dos casos.

Os objetos que chama de normal são [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) e pequenos e eles existem por si próprios e são guardados diretamente na variável (em Python isso não é bem verdade, mas para todos efeitos é isto, pode ser que alguém venha falar que é diferente, mas não muda nada na prática, apenas tudo tem indireção extra que torna a linguagem ineficiente). Então cada referência ao objeto é única, quando você copia o dado está copiando o objeto em si e não sua referência.

## Seu exemplo

Então no primeiro exemplo a referência de `a` está sendo copiada para `l_item` quando chama a função, e o objeto é o mesmo, apenas agora tem duas referências para ele. Uma dessas referências se perdem quando a função termina já que o [parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) é uma variável local que tem o seu [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) vinculado à função. O [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) do objeto é vinculado a ter pelo menos uma referência para ele (Python tem um *garbage collector* que apaga o objeto quando não tiver referência para ele mais).

Então se tem duas referências e o objeto é o mesmo qualquer alteração no objeto reflete para todas variáveis que são as referência para ele.

O mesmo acontece no segundo exemplo. Está fazendo a mesma coisa, quando copia o valor de `a` para `b` está copiando a referência para o objeto e não o objeto, e qualquer alteração feita através de uma variável será refletido na outra variável porque o objeto é o mesmo, não é ele que é copiado.

Então no funco os dois são cópias e agem igual, só porque um deles não tem o sinal de igual (atribuição) não significa que não está atribuindo e não seja uma cópia. Mas todas linguagens decentes copiam sempre o valor da variável, e tipos por referência o seu valor não é objeto e sim a referência, isto que é copiado.

Se deseja mesmo ter dois objetos lista, e quase sempre isso é um erro em tipos por referência, precisa criar um novo objeto e copiar elemento por elemento dele para o outro objeto. Já existe pronto o método `copy()` no tipo de lista e o operador de *slice* (`[:]`) também.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).