# Existe ponteiro no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ponteiro, objetos

Eu estava programando e encontrei uma coisa interessante mas fiquei com dúvida em uma situação.

Eu criei um objeto e referenciei ele assim:

```
a = {a:1,b:2}
```

E depois eu criei outro objeto e atribuí o valor de 'a' nele:

```
b = a
```

Só que quando eu mudava o valor de `b`, os valores de `a` mudavam também.

Isso aconteceu porque eu atribuí não só os valores de `a` para `b` mas porque eu atribuí a referência de um para outro também?

Comment: No JavaScript, os objetos são **sempre** passados por referência, porque, na verdade, o seu valore é sempre a referência e não o valor em si

Comment: Para que os valores não mudem e sejam introduzidos em uma nova variável, sem referẽncia, você pode fazer assim: `b = {...a}` ou `b = Object.assign({}, a)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ponteiro exposto para você não existe, mas [indireções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), valores acessados por referência tem. Seria quase impossível fazer algum código útil sem ter uma forma assim.

Ponteiro é um mecanismo de acesso indireto a um valor e algumas linguagens o expõe para o usuário (o programador), outras preferem mantê-los de forma opaca para simplificar a linguagem.

Então o que você está usando é um valor por referência que internamente usa um ponteiro para causar a indireção, mas não exposto. Então você atribuiu a referência, mesmo que não esteja vendo isto, e assim está acessando o mesmo objeto apontado por duas variáveis diferentes com o mesmo ponteiro, você atribuiu o mesmo ponteiro para elas, sem nem ver por causa da opacidade.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).