# Iterando sobre lista com B Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

Estou tentando realizar web scrapping de uma lista de episodios de uma série com BS. Montei a estrutura abaixo:

```
 #Importando todos os módulos
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib.request as urllib_request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

import pandas as pd

#Colocando a URL da página
url = 'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_epis%C3%B3dios_de_How_I_Met_Your_Mother'

#Fazer request do html para o servidor
req = Request(url)
response = urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
#Convertendo html de byte para str
html = html.decode('UTF-8')
type(html)

#Tratando a str
def trata_html(input):
    " ".join(input.split())
    input.replace('> <', '><')
    return input

html = trata_html(html)

#Criando o objeto BS
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#Trabalhando com as tags

#Puxando todo o conteúdo de tabelas de informações dos episódios
lista_tabela_episodios = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable'})

#Criando listas de elementos para o dataframe:
dataframe_infos_episodios = []

#Selecionando a lista de elementos do cabeçalho para usar como key dos dicionários
cabecalho_lista_episodios = lista_tabela_episodios.find('tr', style='color:black;text-align:center')
lista_episodios = soup.findAll('tr', class_ = 'vevent')

episodio = {}
i = 0

for linha in lista_episodios:

  # Número do episódio:
  episodio['numero_na_serie'] = lista_episodios[i].find('th', scope="row").getText()

  # Nome do episódio:
  episodio['titulo'] = lista_episodios[i].find('td', class_ = 'summary').getText()

  i += 1
  dataframe_infos_episodios.append(episodio)
```

Como output, eu esperava uma lista com o número e titulo de todos os episodios da lista 'lista_episodios', através da iteração de cada item da lista com 'i'. O problema é que meu output é esse:

```
[{'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
 {'numero_na_serie': '207\n\n208', 'titulo': '"Last Forever"  '},
```

E assim até o final da lista...

Há algum problema com meu iterador?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que quando você faz o append de um dicionário você está criando um ponteiro, não uma refêrencia (se pode ver a resposta [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%C3%AAncia) para entender a diferença entre ponteiro e referência). Quando você atualiza o valor do dicionário você está mudando todos os valores que você acrescentou no dataframe, por isso no final todos eles ficam com o valor do episódio final. O que você pode fazer é colocar a declaração do dicionário dentro do loop, assim toda vez o Python estaria alocando uma posição na memória diferente, entendendo que todos os dicionários que você está acresecentando no data frame são diferentes.

Tem outro problema no seu código de estilo é que você não precisa da váriavel i. O `for linha in lista_de_episodios` já coloca na váriavel `linha` o valor de `lista_episodios[i]`. O código reformatado ficaria:

```
for linha in lista_episodios:
    episodio = {}
    episodio['numero_na_serie'] = linha.find('th', scope="row").getText()
    episodio['titulo']=linha.find('td', class_ = 'summary').getText()
    dataframe_infos_episodios.append(episodio)
```