# Qual a finalidade do simbolo "&" na declaração de um objeto?

Tags: c++, sintaxe, declaração-de-variável, referência

Reparei que em algumas declarações de variáveis/objetos se usa `*` para a declaração (assim gerando um ponteiro), mas em alguns casos tem a declaração utilizando `&`.

```
const MyClass & my_class = object.getMyClass();
```

> Para que serve o "&" durante a declaração de um objeto?

Comment: é um operador de *bitwise*, ou seja, operação lógica a nivel de bits. Não consigo agora escrever uma resposta, mas pode ler mais aqui: https://tecdicas.com/bitwise-em-cpp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este símbolo indica que está criando uma referência em vez de um ponteiro, mas funciona de forma análoga (não igual).

Ele faz parte do tipo e não da variável, muito menos do objeto em si, ainda que a variável passará se comportar de acordo com o tipo e o objeto está criado de forma que ele devolva uma referência e não um valor direto. Na verdade igual ao ponteiro.

A referência tem limitações do que pode fazer em relação ao ponteiro, o que inclusive permite certas otimizações por parte do compilador. Por exemplo ele não permite um valor nulo, nem pode apontar para algo arbitrário, portanto é um mecanismo muito mais seguro.

Ele não pode ser [confundido com um *array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)* também, ao contrário do ponteiro. Ele pode até apontar para um local da memória que seja um *array*, mas não é a mesma coisa.

Se não existisse esses símbolos provavelmente um ponteiro seria declarado assim:

```
const pointer<MyClass> my_class = object.getMyClass();
```

e portanto uma referência seria:

```
const reference<MyClass> my_class = object.getMyClass();
```

Já que o tipo é a combinação dos dois nomes (lê-se referência para uma objeto `MyClass`) algumas pessoas preferem a sintaxe assim:

```
const MyClass& my_class = object.getMyClass();
```

Outras preferem assim:

```
const MyClass &my_class = object.getMyClass();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/ReferenceSyntax.cpp).

É estranho porque o símbolo não faz parte da variável, mas C tinha e C++ também tem um problema na forma de declaração, e o símbolo não é adquirido por todas variáveis na mesma linha, então pode fazer confusão quando aproxima do nome do tipo principal. Nada que nunca declarar duas variáveis na mesma linha não resolva.

Pode ver mais sobre as diferenças conceituais em [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Answer (score 0):

A principal diferença entre um ponteiro e uma referência é que a referência nunca pode ser nula, isso é garantido pelo compilador.

Além disso, em C++, o açúcar sintático em torno das referências é um pouco melhor.